# How can I efficiently convert TEI documents into LaTeX?

Tags: conversion, tei

[TEI](https://tei-c.org) documents have a lot of information that can be used for representation and style. Are there any tools to convert such documents into LaTeX in order to create good pdf/html etc. versions?

Comment: Could you provide more information on 'TEI'?

Comment: http://www.tei-c.org/index.xml

Comment: Is it xml markup? Source-code? Binary-blob? Sql database? I can't tell from looking at that website.

Comment: TEI is a special from of XML markup that allows text critical elements and other meta information being added to the normal text

Comment: It is possible to directly process TEI files in ConTeXt. See ConTeXt wiki [article](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/TEI_xml) for details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's an XML defined markup. There are XSLT stylesheets for this format from the same website you link to

https://www.tei-c.org/Tools/Stylesheets/

> This is a set of XSLT 2.0 specifications to transform TEI XML documents to XHTML, to LaTeX, to XSL Formatting Objects, to OOXML (docx), and to ePub format. The files can be downloaded from the Releases area of https://tei.sf.net . They concentrate on the simpler TEI modules, but adding support for other modules is fairly easy. In the main, the setup has been used on ‘new’ documents, ie reports and web pages that have been authored from scratch, rather than traditional TEI-encoded existing material.

Answer (score 1):

Use TEI's OxGarage online service then edit the generated LaTeX to tweak as necessary/desired