# Convert LaTeX to HTML

Tags: pdftex, conversion, html, accessibility, latex2html

Is there a converter that will convert LaTeX to HTML? I have tried several services but the LaTeX diagrams and some of the maths came out weird.

I actually converted the Latex to PDF without a problem. Then I used [an online PDF to HTML converter](http://www.pdfonline.com/convert-pdf-to-html/default.aspx) to convert from PDF to HTML. The square root signs did not appear properly and some of the Cartesian coordinate plane diagrams had nothing on them except the grid.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-plot}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\addtolength{\hoffset}{0.2cm}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.1cm}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.0cm}
\addtolength{\voffset}{-0.7cm}
\linespread{1.3}
\begin{document}

If $x$ is non-positive then $x \leq -\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$     $\hspace{30 mm} $     (6)\\

(4) and (6) tell us that\\

(4)  $-1 \leq x \leq 0$  \\

(6)  If $x$ is non-positive then $x \leq -\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$\\

Therefore $-1 \leq x \leq -\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$\\

\vspace{50 mm}

\begin{align*}
\psgrid[unit=2cm](0,0)(-2,-2)(2,2)
\pnode(-1.8,.87){b}\uput[50](b){b}
\pnode(-1.8,1.8){a}\uput[50](a){a}
\psset{linecolor=green}
\psline[linewidth=1pt](-1.8, 0)(-1.8,4)
\psset{linecolor=green}
\psline[linewidth=1pt](-1.8, 0)(-1.8,-4)
\psset{linecolor=blue}
\psellipticarc(0,0)(2,2){0}{180}
\psset{linecolor=red}
\psline[linewidth=1pt,linestyle=dashed,dash=2pt](-2,2)(-1.41,1.41)
\psset{linecolor=red}
\psline[linewidth=1pt](-1.41,1.41)
\psset{linecolor=red}
\psline[linewidth=1pt]{->}(4,-4)
\psset{linecolor=red}
\psline[linewidth=1pt]{->}(-2,2)(-4,4)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

#### PDF output:

[image]

#### PDF->HTML output:

[image]

Comment: It may help if you describe what techniques you have tried and include examples of what turned out weird.

Comment: Perhaps one of the questions listed at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latex2html is helpful to you?

Comment: @doncherry: And if those don't, there's always the [FAQ](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=LaTeX2HTML).

Comment: So, @XYZ: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: See comment below answer.

Comment: If you indent lines by four spaces they will be shown as block code. You can also click on the `{}` button to indent more than one line ;-)

Comment: @XYZ: I've edited your post to include the regular PDF output (obtained via a `latex`->`dvips`->`ps2pdf` compilation) as well as the PDF->HTML conversion in image form when using [PDFonline.com](http://www.pdfonline.com/convert-pdf-to-html/default.aspx). This should improve your post quality since it clearly shows the problems you're experiencing, as requested by the comments.

Comment: For converting __LaTeX to `.docx`__ 1. convert from LaTeX to HTML using `htlatex` as described in this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39391/202358 and then 2. convert `.html` to `.docx` using LibreOffice: open `.html`, export as `.odt` then open again and save as `.docx`. :)

Answer (score 135):

Using PDF as an intermediate format when converting from LaTeX to HTML is not a very good idea.  LaTeX and HTML are both mostly structural markup languages, which means you use them to describe the document structure (sections, emphasize, formulas etc.), whereas PDF is mostly about the representation of your document on the screen or paper.  When converting LaTeX to PDF, you lose much of the structural information, and it cannot be successfully recovered by conversion from PDF to HTML.

It is much better to convert LaTeX directly to HTML. There are [number of ways](http://web.archive.org/web/20121107120612/http://www.charlietanksley.net/philtex/converting-from-latex/) (Wayback Archive) how to do that, one I would recommend is by using `htlatex`.  It is probably already part of your TeX distribution, is very powerful and flexible, and its use can be as simple as running

```
htlatex mydocument.tex
```

If you tell us more about your environment (which operating system do you use, what is your TeX distribution, your text editor/LaTeX IDE, how you generated the PDF file etc.) we may be able to give you more details on how to use `htlatex`.

Comment: I used MiKTeX 2.9 which I downloaded off the internet onto a computer using Windows 7.  It is TeXworks and some of the options are pdfLaTeX + MakeIndex + BibTeX, LaTeXmk, pdfTeX, pdfLaTeX, pdfLaTeX + MakeInndex + BibTex, XeTeX, XeLaTeX, XeLaTeX + MakeIndex, + BibTex, ConTeXt(LuaTeX), conTeXt(pdfTeX), ConteXt(XeTeX)

Comment: To get htlatex on Ubuntu 14.04: `sudo apt-get install tex4ht`

Comment: `htlatex` not working for modern tex-engines like XeTeX.

Comment: @XYZ do you know how to convert latex to html? I use MiKTeX and TeXworks too.

Comment: @JanHlavacek `htlatex` results this error. `! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfsys@svg@newline ->\Hnewline 
                                
l.230   \pgfusepathqfill}`

Comment: htlatex didn't really understand tikz pictures

Answer (score 31):

I have had good mileage with and would recommend [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/) for converting LaTeX to HTML output.

[Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/) provides capability for applying CSS styling to HTML output and can take care of equation rendering with e.g. MathML and citation/bibliography styling, among many other features, and is well documented.

Comment: Pandoc chokes on e.g. `\lstinputlisting[...]{...}`, specially if you break up a long options list among lines.

Comment: Hi @Harry. It'll be awesome if you may please also include command sequences? I tried pandoc but struggling to make it aware of all the files from my multi-file project. I just end up with main.tex converted, which is pretty much just imports!!

Answer (score 27):

> Is there a converter that will convert LaTeX to HTML?

Yes. [There](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-LaTeX2HTML) [are](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3079/how-do-i-convert-html-to-latex) lots. But you already knew this, as evidenced by your second "question":

> I have tried several services but the LaTeX diagrams and some of the maths came out weird.

"turning out weird" could mean any number of things:

- The document fails to compile
- The document compiles, but is empty or corrupted
- The document compiles and opens, but is somehow faulty.

Each of these categories breaks down further and the solution may well depend on what you used to do the conversion, so as it stands, this question is unanswerable.

For diagrams, one word of general advice I would give is that it might be best to compile the diagrams separately and include them into the html by hand with `<img>` tags. Diagrams are hard. The [`standalone`](http://ctan.org/pkg/standalone) package/class can help with this. See also the [pgf/TikZ externalisation tag](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-external).

Comment: I actually converted the Latex to PDF without a problem.  Then I used www.pdfonline.com to convert from PDF to HTML. The square root signs did not appear properly and some of the Cartesian coordinate plane diagrams  had nothing on them except the grid.

Comment: @XYZ add this information to your question, along with an example of a file that has this problem.

Comment: The second link "are" goes to a question entitled "How do I convert HTML to LaTeX?". Note that is not the question asked, it is the inverse conversion.

Answer (score 25):

You may try to use [pdf2htmlEX](https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX), which is a general PDF to HTML converter. You can compile the LaTeX source to PDF, and then convert the PDF to HTML via pdf2htmlEX. A good reference of pdf2htmlEX is its [wiki page](https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX/wiki). The work-flows are given in the Figure 3 of the article on TUGboat: *Online publishing via pdf2htmlEX* [HTML](http://coolwanglu.github.io/pdf2htmlEX/doc/tb108wang.html) / [PDF](http://coolwanglu.github.io/pdf2htmlEX/doc/tb108wang.pdf).

The screenshot shows the converted HTML (Ubuntu 14.04, Google Chrome 43).

[image]

Comment: Wow, pdf2htmlEX looks awesome: https://coolwanglu.github.io/pdf2htmlEX/demo/cheat.html

Comment: This tool worked perfectly for me, and seems a lot more trustworthy than many other tools displayed by google.

Comment: pdf2htmlEX does not seem to be maintained any more. Too bad, I was hoping it will take off as it seemed promising.

Comment: There is an active fork, at least at the time of writing my comment: https://github.com/pdf2htmlEX/pdf2htmlEX

Comment: @DanielGilbert  looking at the fork, 3 years later now, looks dead also. no change for more than a year or two. That is the problem with open source. You never know when the programmer who made the program decides they had enough and moves on leaving the code behind and if no one takes over, it is all wasted time.

Comment: @DanielGilbert That's not a problem unique to FOSS. Companies abandon / discontinue proprietary products too, but with no recourse. At least the person who made the FOSS contribution made it available for others to pick up if they wanted. Count your blessings.

Answer (score 15):

**Use LaTeX subsets**

LaTeX and its common output formats like PDF are super complicated. Converting all of it to HTML + CSS is close to impossible.

But if you restrict yourself only to a small subset of LaTeX features it becomes 
feasible.

**Lightweight markup languages**

First I recommend that you just try to go with a simpler format like [<strike>Markdown</strike> Asciidoctor](https://cirosantilli.com/markdown-style-guide#use-asciidoc), which can be converted to HTML and PDF by several implementations like pandoc.

I have come to believe that having painless HTML is more important than the infinitely many features of LaTeX.

Furthermore, Asciidoctor is extensible, so if you find anything missing, it is easy to code it up in Ruby, which is arguably much saner than LaTeX scripts.

Here is a [sample article I've written with Asciidoctor](https://cirosantilli.com/oxford-nanopore-river-bacteria) which includes features such as ToC and image references.

For Math, there is already MathJax, and I'm very close [to reaching Nirvana through KaTeX](https://github.com/cirosantilli/asciidoctor-katex-2).

**Softcover**

Another thing to check out, but which I don't recommend as much, is [Softcover](https://github.com/softcover/softcover): it has a LaTeX subset which it calls Polytex that it can convert to HTML. The exact subset is not well documented, but it already handles 99.9% of what we need to make regular books as shown in their documentation https://github.com/softcover/softcover_book/tree/master/chapters : sections, lists, equations, tables, images, references. Softcover does it's magic through [Tralics](https://github.com/softcover/tralics), which does LaTeX to XML.

**Diagrams**

As Seamus said, diagrams are hard, and it is unlikely they will be part of the implementable subset any time soon, so use images, ideally generated from a sublanguage embedded in the main markup that gets passed to an external image generator. Asciidoctor for example [supports this out-of-the-box](https://asciidoctor.org/docs/asciidoctor-diagram/).

Alternatively, generate the images through a command line tool like gplot or pyplot, and then build the PDF with a Makefile that first builds the images and then the PDF.

Comment: If anyone can guess why the downvote, let me know.

Answer (score 14):

There is a [lwarp](https://ctan.org/pkg/lwarp) package on CTAN which treats tikz diagrams really well:
[image: example]

Answer (score 13):

In my perspective none works better than [LaTeXML](http://dlmf.nist.gov/LaTeXML/).

Here is a [ready-made docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/sumdoc/texlive-2017/) with latexml installed and the instructions to convert tex documents.
Its very much tightly integrated with LaTeX and delivers same looking output in html as in pdf.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 8):

I'm currently developing a free open source tool that can convert LaTeX to a single HTML file. Its called PDBF (https://github.com/uds-datalab/PDBF) and runs on win/linux/mac.

Instructions:

- Make sure you have a Java Runtime (version >= 1.7) installed
- Download latest version of PDBF: https://github.com/uds-datalab/PDBF/archive/gh-pages.zip
- Unpack archive
- Change current dir to unpacked folder
- Run: java -jar pdbf.jar /path/to/sometexfile.tex

Resulting HTML file is placed in the same folder as the source tex file with the same name as the source tex file.

Technical details:
The PDBF compiler basically uses a regular tex engine to compile your pdf and then stores the pdf as base64 encoded javascript string in the HTML and then includes a slightly modified version of pdf.js (The free and open source pdf engine of firefox) into the HTML to display that pdf.

Hope you like my project. Feel free to contact me through github if you have suggestions or encounter bugs.

Comment: What do you gain from running the standard PDF previewer of Chrome/Firefox, etc ...?

Comment: @Paulo Ney 1. You can then open the html files also with browsers that have no PDF viewer included. 2. It allowed us to extend PDF.js to make charts and other things in the resulting html interactive ([example](https://infosys.uni-saarland.de/publications/p1972-dittrich.html))

Answer (score 7):

As previously observed using PDF format for converting from LaTeX to HTML is very bad idea. Here you will find a comprehensive list of programs that convert LaTeX to HTML (Note not all of those programs are capable of converting pure TeX.)

[TeX FAQ: Conversion from (La)TeX to HTML](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-LaTeX2HTML)

I am familiar with three of these programs: LaTeX2HTML, TeX4ht, and Hevea. All of them have their strengths and weaknesses and they use different approaches.  TeX4ht is included in TeXLive and MiKTeX unlike other two and from the point of view of theoretical CS is a "correct" way to do conversion (not surprisingly it was written [by a (now deceased) member of the CS department at Ohio State](https://www.ctan.org/author/gurari)). If you have just a few pages to convert,  probably the right approach for you would be to chose any of the three and then do some manual editing. Now you have to be careful. For example Hevea will try to use HTML tags for things like square root while TeX4ht will use bitmap images for any math expressions. Since pure HTML has a poor support for mathematics the first approach can quickly get into trouble but when it works the output is really beautiful.

As for diagrams and pictures, all of the above programs to my knowledge rely on ImageMagic to do image conversion. Hevea has to be run multiple times (it is actually bunch of scripts) and the proper way to use it is by writing a Makefile (Unix again). I would actually convert images and diagrams manually using GraphicMagic which is IMHO far more stable and better batch image processor than ImageMagic.

Comment: What do you mean by "theoretical CS correct" more precisely?

Comment: He means that there is no provably correct HTML output for any given LaTeX input, and so authors of conversion software need to make creative decisions on what to output.

Answer (score 4):

[RtextDoc](http://jwork.org/rtextdoc) has a built in Latex to Html converter

Comment: How well does it cope with the type of documents the poster is interested in?

Answer (score 4):

You might want to consider using [DocOnce](https://hplgit.github.io/doconce/doc/web/index.html) as primary format instead of LaTeX:

> DocOnce is a modestly tagged (Markdown-like) markup language targeting scientific reports, software documentation, books, blog posts, and slides involving much math and code in the text. From DocOnce source you can generate LaTeX, Sphinx, HTML, IPython notebooks, Markdown, MediaWiki, and other formats. This means that you from a single source can get the most up-to-date publishing technologies for paper, tablets, and phones.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another software [plastex](https://github.com/plastex/plastex) that is under active development. It looks very promising and the [Stacks project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/) is based on plastex.

Comment: This is lovely. Seeing (from http://plastex.github.io/plastex/) that it is used by commercial projects such as SAS, CourseBuilder, it seems to me the most promising way forward.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to do the same thing, and found this post. But... even though my book doesn't have fancy mathematical formulas, I thought what I developed could be of use to future generation of Latex book writers who are frustrated by HTML conversion.

I really needed to convert my Latex book to HTML. Having had experience with writing my own plain-text to HTML converters for some personal project software, and server side programming, I wrote this PHP script, that **solves the problem for simple Latex documents** using Regular Expressions.

By simple, I mean, **only converts** the following items:

1. Images with "Figure" caption (automatic Figure **N** inserted)
2. Converts `begin{lstlisting}...end{lstlisting}` to `<code>...</code>`
3. Accurately converts `\textbf`, `\textit` and `\texttt`, so long as you follow the rule of nesting italics inside bolds (and not the other way around) to `<b>`, `<i>` and `<span style = "font-family: Courier; font-weight: bold; color: #FF4500">` respectively. Change the color if need to.
4. `\section` to `<H1>`
5. `\subsection` to `<H2>`
6. `\subsubsection` to `<H3>`
7. Note, `\begin{figure}` will be converted to `<img src = ""/>`

The last item (7) requires additional attention. You must replicate your image folder elsewhere, and tweak the PHP script to point to it. In this example it is set to `http://localhost/` it is assumed that you have some base image folder for entire manuscript. Make sure it exists somewhere and specify it in this part of the script.

One idea is... if possible, you can convert your mathematical formulas to images, use those images in your Latex document, and you should have no problem with the conversion using this script. Unfortunately, HTML doesn't really support math too well, at least at this time. Good luck!

It also does some other *silly* clean-up tweaking, like converting <p></p> to space, just to make sure there are no HTML redundancies.

The script is surprisingly simple. All glory to Regular Expressions.

It is also flexible - If you encounter errors, tweak it to your own heart desire. But be warned - it is quite important to perform some replacements in the exact order they appear in the script. Otherwise, you might break it.

Run following PHP script on your localhost, and make sure `source.tex` is your Latex manuscript and that it resides in the same folder from which you are running the script:

```
<?php

chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
$file = file_get_contents("source.tex");

$figure_counter = 1;
$all_codes = array();

// Replace code 
$file = preg_replace('/.lstset(.*)/', '', $file);                                   // replace code block
$file = preg_replace('/.begin{lstlisting}(.*)/', '<code>', $file);              // replace code block
$file = preg_replace('/.end{lstlisting}/', '</code>', $file);                       // replace code block

// Replace all <code>....</code> with CODE0, CODE1, CODE2, ... etc.
// It's best  to do code clean up before any thing else
// Clean up < brackets inside <code> blocks, memorize all codes for later re-insertion,
function callback($matches) { global $all_codes; $M = str_replace(">", "&gt;", str_replace(">","&lt;",$matches[0])); $C = count($all_codes); $all_codes[$C] = $M; return "\n\nCODE".$C."\n\n"; }
$file = preg_replace_callback('/<code>(\r|\n|.*?)<\/code>/s', 'callback', $file);   

// order is important here --  must convert TTT first, before BF AND IT
$file = preg_replace_callback('/.texttt{(.*?)}/', 'callbackT', $file);          // mono text

// convert text styles
$file = preg_replace('/.textbf{(.*?)}/', '<b>$1</b>', $file);           // bold text
$file = preg_replace('/.textit{(.*?)}/', '<i>$1</i>', $file);           // italic text
function callbackT($matches) { return '<span style = "font-family:Courier; font-weight: bold; color: #FF4500">' . str_replace(">", "&gt;", str_replace("<","&lt;",substr($matches[0],8,-1))) . '</span>'; }

// convert sections to headers
$file = preg_replace('/.section{(.*?)}/', '<h1>$1</h1>', $file);            // H1
$file = preg_replace('/.subsection{(.*?)}/', '<h2>$1</h2>', $file);         //  H2
$file = preg_replace('/.subsubsection{(.*?)}/', '<h3>$1</h3>', $file);      //  H3

// Replace images
$file = preg_replace('/.begin{figure}(.*)/', '', $file);                        // replace images
$file = preg_replace('/.end{figure}(.*)/', '', $file);                      // replace images
$file = preg_replace('/ .centering/', '', $file);                       // replace images
function callback1($matches) { global $figure_counter; return "<p>Figure " . ($figure_counter++) . ": " . substr($matches[0], 10, -1) . "</p>"; }
$file = preg_replace_callback('/    .caption{(.*?)}/', 'callback1', $file);                     // replace images

$file = preg_replace('/ .includegraphics(.*?){"\.\.(.*?)"}/', '<p><img src = "http://localhost/$2.png"></p>', $file);                       // replace images
$file = preg_replace('/ .label{(.*?)}/', '', $file);                        // replace images

// Insert paragraphs
$file = preg_replace('/(.*?)\r\n\r\n/', "\n<p>$1</p>\n", $file);

// just in case
$file = preg_replace('/<p><p>/', "<p>" . "\n", $file);
$file = preg_replace('/<\/p><\/p>/', "</p>" . "\n", $file);
$file = preg_replace('/<p>\nFigure/', "<p>Figure", $file);
$file = preg_replace('/<p>Figure\n/', "<p>Figure", $file);

// As the last step, reinsert codes, to avoid messing them up by previous replacements
for ($i = 0; $i < count($all_codes); $i++)
    $file = preg_replace('/CODE'.$i.'/', $all_codes[$i], $file);

// Not sure why this is still the case but it is..
$file = preg_replace('/\n<p><\/code><\/p>/', "</code>", $file);

$style = "<style>body {background:white !important; color: black !important;} code { border: 1px solid gray; padding: 4px; } img { margin: 0 auto; position: relative; display: block; text-align: center; width: 75%; max-width: 500px; }</style>";

/* Print out the book in HTML! */   
print "<body>" . $style . "\n" . $file . "</body>";

?>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `pandoc` does this already (@Harry's answer), plus much much more.  Did u try pandoc already?  I used it for small cases, but it was great.  I'd be interested to know if there's anything in this script that's not accomplished in 1 line using pandoc.

Answer (score 0):

You may try importing your LaTeX inside TeXmacs (assuming that your LaTeX file is clean, the result is usually OK) and then export to Html.  TeXmacs provides several options in the preferences: convert mathematics to images, MathML, or MathJax, and there are a few nice CSS stylesheets among which you can choose.  Look at the website of the TeXmacs author for a bunch of articles and how they export to Html.

Answer (score 0):

[arXiv now offers papers in HTML format](https://blog.arxiv.org/2023/12/21/accessibility-update-arxiv-now-offers-papers-in-html-format/), which means that if one uploads one's paper to arXiv as a LaTeX project, one automatically gets the HTML version of it.

Comment: Behind the scenes, this is done with LaTeXML, which is mentioned in [another answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/384821/107497).  I would also implore people to not upload a paper to arXiv just to get the html version.

Comment: @Teepeemm Yes, it's mostly for people who don't want to use LaTeXML offline and whose papers are ready for arXiv.