# Convert Latex to MathJax-HTML

Tags: tex4ht, html, mathjax

Is there any tool that can convert Latex documents to HTML documents, so that all math is presented with [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/)?

(Obviously, it is fairly easy to hack together a quick Perl script that is able to do a crude conversion, but I am interested in a bit more robust solutions — at least it should get all cross-references right automatically.)

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39309/convert-latex-to-html is a similar question, although doesn't specify "MathJax".

Answer (score 33):

**Update 07/2020:**

The code bellow is not needed anymore. TeX4ht has now full support for the MathJax output. The equivalent of the code bellow is this:

```
make4ht filename.tex "mathml,mathjax"
```

If you want to keep your LaTeX math as plain text, use just:

```
make4ht filename.tex "mathjax"
```

`make4ht` is replacement for `htlatex` that converts to HTML5 and UTF-8 by default, so no special configurations as in the old answer are necessary.

---

**Original answer:**

You can use `TeX4ht`. It can output math as `mathml` which can be then displayed with `mathjax`. You can also configure `html` header to load `mathjax` script from `mathjax's cdn`:

```
\Preamble{xhtml,mathml}
\Configure{VERSION}{}
\Configure{DOCTYPE}{\HCode{<!DOCTYPE html>\Hnewline}}
\Configure{HTML}{\HCode{<html>\Hnewline}}{\HCode{\Hnewline</html>}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<meta charset="UTF-8" />\Hnewline}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<meta name="generator" content="TeX4ht
(http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/\string~gurari/TeX4ht/)" />\Hnewline}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<link
         rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
         href="\expandafter\csname aa:CssFile\endcsname" />\Hnewline}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<script type="text/javascript"\Hnewline
src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"\Hnewline
></script>\Hnewline}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<style type="text/css">\Hnewline
  .MathJax_MathML {text-indent: 0;}\Hnewline
</style>\Hnewline}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

With this config file, we request to output math as `mathml`, then configure `html` header so resulting file is `html5`. Save it as for example `ht5mjlatex.cfg` and then call from command line:

```
htlatex filename.tex "ht5mjlatex.cfg, charset=utf-8" " -cunihtf -utf8"
```

or you can use  William F. Hammond's [script](http://www.albany.edu/%7Ehammond/demos/Html5/arXiv/) (at bottom of the page)

Comment: And this has the advantage that browsers that can display MathML (natively or via a plugin) can avoid the necessity of loading MathJaX.

Comment: This is certainly better than nothing, but I would prefer to keep the HTML source code somewhat readable. Very simple equations seem to produce dozens of lines of mathml markup...

Answer (score 11):

I would personally prefer using [`pandoc`](http://pandoc.org/index.html) for this task, It's a one step solution and the output is much better in my opinion.

> To convert files from one markup format into another, pandoc is your swiss-army knife.

This command should fit most purposes:

```
pandoc document.tex --standalone --mathjax --output document.html
```

It will create a single HTML file with a javascript reference to mathjax.js. Pandoc is extensively documented and [other methods for displaying math in HTML](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#math-rendering-in-html) are available.

Comment: Those sample command lines show how to convert a file with "TeX math" to HTML; note the ".text" and not "tex" extension. The question asks how to convert "LaTeX documents" to HTML. Can pandoc do that?

Comment: Pandoc _can_ convert complete .tex documents to HTML, but it was not clear from the answer so I improved it. I hope this will help me remove your -1 vote :).

Comment: @DoronBehar How do you know that he downvoted?