# on Tex4ht conversion to HTML, can this conversion be improved?

Tags: tex4ht, latex2html

I have been trying tex4ht and comparing its output to Latex2html (l2h).

I still find l2h to produce better math in the HTML than tex4ht. But it could be I am not doing something right and I thought to check with the experts here.

I'll show a very small example, and show the commands used, and show the output I get from l2h and tex4h. Clearly the l2h Math looks better. The math from tex4h is not straight on the same line as the text around it, also the `\prime` shows up like just a straight up tick instead of a real math `\prime`. Also some letters with tex4ht seems to be fussy looking, while other Math letters seems to be sharp. Also the letter `v` looks different from a real `v` letter in math mode.

I hope someone can spot something I am doing wrong when it comes to using tex4ht

Here is the tex file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}%
\usepackage{html}
\begin{document}

Where $\left[M\right]_{v^{\prime}\to v}$ is the change of basis matrix which
when applied to $\mathbf{x}_{v^{\prime}}$ returns the coordinates of the
vector w.r.t. basis $v$

\end{document}
```

Here is the Latex2html and htlatex commands used to make the HTML

```
latex2html t4.tex
htlatex t4.tex
```

Here is a screen shot of the output from l2h

[image]

Here is a screen shot of the output from tex4ht

[image]

### specs

> Linux mint xfce 14, tex4ht
>
> tex4ht -v
>   tex4ht.c (2009-01-31-07:33 kpathsea)
>
> latex2html -v
>   This is LaTeX2HTML Version 2008 (1.71)
>
> latex -v
>   pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)
>   kpathsea version 6.1.0

**Update**

Thanks to suggestion by @cmhughes below, I tried the command suggested. It improved the output for sure, but the `->` has too much spaces between them. Here is a screen shot as seen on Chrome browser (same browser used for the above screen shots). But I would use over the last command.

```
   mk4ht mzlatex t4.tex "html,mathplayer"
```

and now looking at the file 4.xht

[image]

**btw**, when I tried the above `mk4ht` command on other latex documents I have, I now get syntax errors which do not show up when I use the command `htlatex foo.tex`. Here is one example:

```
mk4ht mzlatex report.tex "html,mathplayer"

! Display math should end with $$.
<to be read again> 
                   \bgroup 
l.470 \end{equation}

?
```

So, I am not sure I want to use this command if I have to go now edit all my latex files again to make it work with mathml generation. I do not know what other incompatibilities this will bring up and if I do this change, will the file work again with Latex?

Comment: how about `mk4ht mzlatex myfile.tex "html,mathplayer"`?

Comment: Wouldn't you rather use `\to` instead of `->`?

Comment: @AndrewStacey, thanks! yes ofcourse, much better. I have updated now all images again.

Comment: @Nasser you can also convert to html5 and mathjax using tex4ht. see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68962/2891

Comment: @michal.h21, thanks! I did not know this, will look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution is to change the default `density` when tex4ht calls imagemagick's `convert` in tex4ht.env.

This is at line 167 in my version where it says:

```
G.
Gif exist zz%%4.ps DEL zz%%4.ps >nul
Gif exist %%3 DEL %%3 >nul
Gdvips -E -Ppdf -mode ibmvga -D 110 -f %%1 -pp %%2 > zz%%4.ps
Gconvert -trim +repage -density 110x110 -transparent "#FFFFFF" zz%%4.ps %%3
Gif exist zz%%4.ps DEL zz%%4.ps >nul
```

Just change `110x110` to `500x500`. Actually for your inline example this makes an appropriately high resolution `[M]`, but much too large so this would need to be tweaked, possibly with the line above as well.

Maybe this could be done in a configuration file instead, so the original file isn't modified.