# displaying TeX in web app

Tags: amsmath, htlatex, mathjax, mathml

First I tried to ask this question on stackoverflow but it looks like that it's TeX specific.

I'm having a TeX file on server, and need to display it in web page. The first thing I was thinking about was `MathJax` javascript TeX renderer (it renders TeX inside browser). But it does not support stuff like `renewcommand` or `\begin{theorem}...\end{theorem}`. So it looks like everything should be compiled on server side.

And here are my questions:

1. Compiling TeX to MathML will be the easiest way for me... Still I can't find TeX to MathML converter? Can you advise me an adequate TeX to MathML converter?
2. Does MathML covers common part of tex stuff?
3. Is it possible to change automaticaly (e.g. with some utility) stuff like `\begin{theorem}...\end{theorem}` to something that can be compiled without any packages (so that I can path TeX to MathJAX interpriter).

Comment: actually, I asked a similar question here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127867/javascript-latex-to-html-interpreter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not really understand all parts of your question.

1. tex4ht can be used to convert (La)TeX to MathML. Read more at: http://www.tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn-commands.html#QQ1-9-37
2. There was similar question here: [Convert Latex to MathJax-HTML](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68916/convert-latex-to-mathjax-html) about converting LaTeX to MathML and even loading mathjax scripts.
3. Not every (La)TeX construction can be easily converted into MathML, but in general, this works.
4. There is also path via SVG (equations converted to SVG). But, once again, tex4ht is used…