# Javascript LaTeX to HTML interpreter?

Tags: conversion, html, javascript

Is there a possibility to 'render' latex code with your browser?

I have some *.tex files which I would like to render a HTML version of (with HTML-navigation, hyperlinks, etc). However - running some tex2html converter everytime is quite annoying, especially since I use a lot of special packages that are not supported by most converters I tried so far, so I would need to post-process the files everytime I change something in my source document, which happens very often.

What I would really like to have is a javascript library that parses a TeX file and renders an HTML webpage from it using DOM. It doesn't need to be complete in the sense that all CTAN packages are supported, but it should be extendable in the sense that I can plug in my own javascript code to render some self-defined environments and commands.

So what I'm looking for is a javascript to HTML interpreter. Is there such a thing, or would I need to write something up myself?

PS: I know about MathJax, which does an excellent job at rendering math, but I would like to render whole documents, including preamble and custom command definitions.

Comment: I don't know anything like that, but if you are going to write something on your own you may be interested in [FlyLatex](https://github.com/alabid/flylatex) and [Pandoc](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc). I'd personally use something like Textile with [Jekyll](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Jekyll), unless you can find/create something with LaTeX, I'd like that more. Good luck!

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101977/texlive-js-possible

Comment: Neither javascript nor HTML -- but do you know [dvisvgm](http://dvisvgm.sourceforge.net/)? It converts dvi to [svg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Svg) which most modern browsers render natively.

Comment: @ Trylks: I will give pandoc a try. My documents are huge (200+ pages), and the primary output should still be pdf, so switching to another source language is not really an option.

Comment: @ David Carlile: I stumbled upon it before posting my question. It's nice, but it outputs pdf. I want HTML output.

Comment: @ Alex: Nice shot, but I was hoping for something that not only renders, but also can make use of HTML capabilities - for example, having each section on a separate page with working hyperlinks.

Comment: @carsten svg and dvisvgm support hyperlinks, but as of now dvisvgm doesn't handle internal links between different pages. This could change though.

Comment: @ Alex: That would be seriously cool, I'll have a look.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I think I wrote almost exactly what you are asking for: [LaTeX.js](http://latex.js.org). I got most of the standard LaTeX macros working exactly as they should; the parsing of the text is pretty much perfect. So the hard work is done, now it's just about adding more macros.

For instance, I have not implemented tables yet, and I haven't implemented cross-references yet. Those will be next, I think, but it might take a few more weeks or so.

However, your PS is not going to be possible with LaTeX.js. TeX (and thus LaTeX) cannot be successfully parsed as a context-free grammar, which is exactly what I am doing. So loading packages and parsing the preamble will not be possible.