# How does an academic publisher work with LaTeX file to produce html pages?

Tags: math-mode, conversion, html

My teacher sent an academic paper written with LaTeX format file to hindawi.com publisher.
They did something with our paper and has a public html page like this:      http://www.hindawi.com/journals/jam/2011/464832/

I want to ask what they are doing to have a html page with same format as the LaTeX file (with math equation, annotation, ...like that)

I want to build a website to store academic papers (with input is LaTeX file, output is html page). And I don't know how work with my LaTeX file? (Don't say with me that I must typing all again)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i haven't actually looked at the paper you reference, but know that mathjax is used to generate html files containing math, using "real" math symbols from fonts rather than bitmapped images.  this is the method used to produce the reviews of math books and articles on [mathscinet](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/).  (access to mathscinet requires a subscription; many universities have such subscriptions through their libraries.)

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68962/2891 for method of converting latex to html with mathjax for math. see also some examples http://www.albany.edu/~hammond/demos/Html5/arXiv/ produced with this method

Comment: The paper you cite has all the math changed to svg (there are several tex to svg convertors around i can't tell which was used) It is probably simpler to use mathjax (and leave the tex maths as tex to be converted by the javascript in the browser). For the main latex to html conversion I would probably use latexml (but tex4ht is also good)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't need to retype the whole thing, but you will almost certainly need to put some effort (per paper) into adjusting the conversion and proofreading, so you should be sure that this is what you want to do, rather than hosting .pdf files somewhere.

That said, among other file converters you might like to look at `tex4ht` and `pandoc`, two tools for converting LaTeX to other formats.

In particular there have been some good reports of [tex4ht](https://www.tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn.html).  You may like to search this site for `[tex4ht]` or `[html]` to get an idea of what people are doing with it.

There may be copyright implications depending on the terms attached to the papers (even if you wrote them) - you should check if the website is for more than just your own use.