# i dont want png files for the math in tex4ht

Tags: tex4ht

When I convert equations using tex4ht most of them are coming like png files. how to get the html converted instead of png file.

Thanks
Kumar

Comment: Please see other posts on this site: http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=tex4ht+png You will have to convert to MathML instead of png then. There is not html for equations, afaIk.

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68962/2891