# TeX4ht superscript symbol problem

Tags: tex4ht

I have small tex file which is as the below

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%test.tex%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass{article}

\def\mysubsup#1#2#3{#1_{#2}^{#3}}

\begin{document}

This is small sample $\mysubsup{P}{2}{3}$

\end{document}
```

When I run as the below

htlatex test.tex "xhtml, mathltx, early_, early^"

The output html has the missing character of "^"

This is small sample

How to retrieve the superscript symbol

Thanks
Baskar

Comment: This happens only with the macro. Its works fine when the superscript is typed in directly. (just an observation)

Comment: In the generated html, for the directly typed formula, the super and subscripts are of smaller font *and* the html tags `<sup>` and `<sub>` are present. For the macro version, the font change html tags are still present, but the `<sup>` and `<sub>` html tags are missing.

Comment: The root cause of the problem is that argument "early^" wrongly passing to tex4ht option as "early" only. to avoid this I have used for "early^^". Kindly request to fix the problem in htlatex argument. Regards Baskar

Answer (score 4):

Subscripts and superscripts in macros are common source of problems in `tex4ht`, it is usually needed to redefine these macros in `tex4ht` patch files, or in the custom config file. `early_` and `early^` options try to fix this problem, but the fail often.

Since in your case the macro is defined by you in the preamble, best solution is to modify it to be compatible:

```
 \def\mysubsup#1#2#3{{#1}\sb{#2}\sp{#3}}
```

first change is to include your first argument in a group, in order to include the whole contents of the argument in the base. `\sb` and `\sp` macros works for subscripts resp. superscripts without problems

The default output with `htlatex test.tex "xhtml,mathltx`:

[image]

You may get better output with `mathml` option, but it works only in Firefox browser (you can [use mathjax to render mathml in other browsers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68962/2891)