# Converting Latex to MsWord .doc or .rtf

Tags: latex-to-word

I understand, that similar questions were already asked here, and I have tried some of suggested solutions (latex2rtf, converting output pdf to doc with different convertors), but didn't find one that works for me.

What are my circumstances:
I work on Windows 8.1, in TexStudio, using TexLive. I use xelatex, because I need Times New Roman Cyrillic in output pdf. My text are mostly in Russian and English, don't contain equations, but contain illustrations and text fragments in Oldchurchslavonic and Greek. I use biblatex and biber for building bibliography.

Often I need to send documents in .doc format, because many journals in my knowledge area don't accept articles in .tex or .pdf. So LaTeX fits perfectly in my workflow except of the final stage.

I tried to use latex2rtf, but run into some encoding problems. What I did finally was converting pdf to doc with trial verstion of Nitro PDF and then spending about two hours cleaning the file from double spaces, hyphens turned into dashes, unexpected line breaks etc. It was definitely not the best solutoin, but I don't have time to search a different one.

Is there any solution for converting latex to .doc or .rtf that will work under described circumstances OR a pdf to doc converter that produces editable .doc?

Comment: Unless I misunderstood, don't you already have a method to produce an editable .doc from pdf?

Comment: You probably won't find a better workflow than what you're doing. If there are particular TeX constructions that you know cause problems when you get to the pdf->word conversion you might try to avoid them in the original source document.

Comment: @PaulGessler It is editable in the sense that I can edit it, but not in the sense, that I can work with it right after the .doc was produced. As I mentioned before, it requires cleanup, and I had to do again significant part of work, that was already done in LaTeX (Adding captions to illustations, adding hyphens) and also clean some unnecessary formatting added by converter.

Comment: @EthanBolker Thanks, I'll try what I can do in this direction. Making a pdf without hyphens already made the task easier. But I still didn't found, why and when do the converters add linebreaks at the end of the line, in the middle of the paragraph. If I will get rid of this problem, this workflow will be satisfactory at least.

Comment: @yukari Well this is a difficult question because `TeX` is quite different from `Word` and in fact from all the WYSIWYG text processors. Another handicap is that `TeX` is able to work with very complex typographical tasks meanwhile in `Word` it's impossible. That's the reason why there is not a easy and almost magic tool for _translate_ from `LaTeX` to `Word`. The most of times you'll need to fix a lot of things as you say and I'm not sure if [pandoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandoc) can help you with this.

Answer (score 8):

Another possibility is to convert LaTeX to HTML (see [Convert LaTeX to HTML](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39309/convert-latex-to-html)) and then import the HTML file from Word.

Comment: This is a good idea for documents without math, yes, I agree.

Answer (score 4):

I use http://www.grindeq.com/index.php?p=latex2word which works OK.  I usually have to fix the formatting and references quite a bit.

I also use http://hutchinson.belmont.ma.us/tth/ which does a fine job of creating html from latex.  The html imports a lot of the math and most of the references just fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you ready to go with commercial format, then Chikri https://www.chikrii.com/products/ and GrindEq https://www.grindeq.com/ are the best...

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is more than 6 years old, but I thought I share my answer anyway since I encountered the problem myself. What worked perfectly for me is converting the PDF to Word using Adobe Acrobat Pro: https://acrobat.adobe.com/us/en/acrobat/acrobat-pro.html#

If it is a one-time problem like for a thesis submission there is also a free trial otherwise quite expensive...