# customizing bst: edition number

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

please see my alternative question below. :)

---

I'm currently working on a bst file for a multivolume companion (approx. 1800 pages in total). By using `makebst`, I tried to apply the guidelines that my publisher gave to me. Yet, the resulting bst file is not satisfying all my needs.

These are the guidelines:

> **Monographs:**
>   Alpha, B. (<sup>edition number</sup>year). book title. publisher.
>   Gamma, D./Epsilon, Z. (eds., year).  booktitle. publisher.
>   **Articles:**
>   Iota, K. (year). article title, journal name volume: pages.
>   **Articles in companions:**
>   Ny, L. (year). article title, "in:" E. Ditor (ed., year), book title. publisher. pages.

I have already inserted the "ed., "/"eds., " before the year. Now I'm struggling with the edition number that should be superscripted right in front of the year. There ist still a ", " before the edition number. Also, it should appear in the in-text citation (e.g., "Alpha (<sup>edition number</sup>year, page)").

I would appreciate if some of you could have a look at the bst file. And maybe tell me how to get rid of the extra ", ", and how to add the edition number to the in-text citation.

---

I bet my problems are way easier to fix with `biblatex`. I have already customized a bbx file, that satisfyies the guidelines from above. But, the publisher wants to diferent in-text citation styles:

> **in-text citation:** Alpha (<sup>edition number</sup>year, page)
>   **footnote citation:** Alpha (<sup>edition number</sup>year) page

At the moment (as I'm using bibtex with natbib), I modified the `\footnote` command to set a boolean variable to `true`. This way, my modified `\citet` command checks if the citation is inside the normal text or a footnote. (I exspect this to end up in a much higher compilation time due to setting the boolean variavble to `true` and `false` at each `\footnote` and to check the variable at each `\citet`.) This modification is not perfect yet. (Cf. `\citet{Alpha:2002}` => "Alpha (2002, )")

Thank you so much or your help.
rsa-krypto

---

bst-test.tex:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{natbib}
    \bibpunct[:\ ]{(}{)}{;}{a}{}{;}

\let\svfootnote\footnote
\renewcommand{\footnote}[2][\thefootnote]{%
    \stepcounter{footnote}%
    \gdef\infootnote{T}%
    \svfootnote[#1]{#2\gdef\infootnote{F}}%
}
\gdef\infootnote{F}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\citefoot}[2][]{%
    \@ifnextchar[%
    {\citeauthor{#2} (\citeyear{#2})}%  w
    {\citeauthor{#2} (\citeyear{#2}) #1}%   w/o
}
\newcommand{\citetxt}[2][]{%
    \@ifnextchar[%
    {\citeauthor{#2} (\citeyear{#2})}%  w
    {\citeauthor{#2} (\citeyear{#2}, #1)}%  w/o
}
\renewcommand{\citet}[2][]{%
    \if T\infootnote%
        \citefoot[#1]{#2}%
    \else%
        \citetxt[#1]{#2}%
    \fi%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    Dies ist ein Testdokument zum Prüfen der bst-Datei.

    \infootnote

    \footnote{Cf. \citet[12]{Alpha:2002}.}

    \citet{Alpha:2002};
    \citet[13]{Gamma:2015};
    \citet[14]{Iota:1998};
    \citet[15]{Ny:2018}

    \bibliographystyle{test-companion}
    \bibliography{test-companion}
\end{document}
```

test-companion.bib:

```
@book{Alpha:2002,
    Author = {Beta Alpha},
    Note = {(= optional note)},
    Publisher = {Chicago},
    Title = {Book title},
    Year = {2002},
    edition = {2}}

@book{Gamma:2015,
    editor = {Delta Gamma and Zeta Epsilon},
    Publisher = {Berlin},
    Title = {Another book},
    Year = {2015}}

@article{Iota:1998,
    Author = {Kappa Iota},
    Journal = {journal name},
    Volume = {24},
    Pages = {11--18},
    Title = {article title},
    Year = {1998}}

@incollection{Ny:2018,
    Author = {Lambda Ny},
    Booktitle = {book title},
    Editor = {E. Ditor},
    Pages = {93--129},
    Publisher = {London},
    Title = {article title},
    Year = {2018}}
```

EDIT:
test-companion.bst
https://pastebin.com/TnFxFwXq

EDIT2:
babelbst.tex
https://pastebin.com/k1p1TkZ2

Comment: Hmm, I can't give you my bst file. Too much characters... Any ideas?

Comment: You can upload the `.bst` file to file pasting website such as https://pastebin.com/ or https://0bin.net/ or https://gist.github.com/. Please do not upload it to a file sharing website where the file has to be downloaded (additional minus points for packing it into a `.zip`).

Comment: A `biblatex` solution would also be possible but I serisously doubt that your prublisher can accept `biblatex` submissions. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864 and the recent https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/436554/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/435658/35864 for two examples of people who could not submit `biblatex` bibliographies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to hack your `.bst` file a bit. See https://gist.github.com/moewew/ac72ac1c5194b146afb5ba5f6b55f928/revisions, the diff is

```
--- test-companion.bst  2018-06-26 10:08:57.485028100 +0200
+++ test-companion.bst  2018-06-26 09:52:36.723647200 +0200
@@ -683,16 +683,26 @@
   if$
 }

-FUNCTION {format.edition}
+FUNCTION {format.superedition}
 { edition duplicate$ empty$
+    { pop$ "" }
+    { superscript }
+  if$
+}
+
+FUNCTION {format.edition}
+{ edition duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
     {
-      pop$ ""
-    }
-    {
-      superscript
+      output.state mid.sentence =
+        { "l" }
+        { "t" }
+      if$ change.case$
+      "edition" bibinfo.check
+      " " * bbl.edition *
     }
   if$
 }
+
 INTEGERS { multiresult }
 FUNCTION {multi.page.check}
 { 't :=
@@ -931,7 +941,7 @@
       if$
     }
   if$
-  format.edition output
+  format.superedition swap$ write$
   format.date "year" output.check
   date.block
   format.btitle "title" output.check
@@ -1294,6 +1304,12 @@
   short.list
   "("
   *
+  edition duplicate$ empty$
+  short.list key field.or.null = or
+     { pop$ "" }
+     { "$^{" swap$ * "}$" * }
+  if$
+  *
   year duplicate$ empty$
   short.list key field.or.null = or
      { pop$ "" }
```

Additionally, you'll need to make sure that postnotes are recognised properly. The footnote detection is more idiomatic with a boolean/`\if...` instead of a string variable.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{natbib}
    \bibpunct[:\ ]{(}{)}{;}{a}{}{;}

\newif\ifinfootnote
\let\svfootnote\footnote
\renewcommand{\footnote}[2][\thefootnote]{%
    \stepcounter{footnote}%
    \svfootnote[#1]{\infootnotetrue#2}%
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\rsacitenopost}[1]{\citeauthor{#1} (\citeyear{#1})}
\newcommand*{\rsacitepost}[2][]{\citeauthor{#2} (\citeyear{#2}\ifinfootnote) #1\else, #1)\fi}

\renewcommand*{\citet}{%
  \@ifnextchar[%]
    {\rsacitepost}
    {\rsacitenopost}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Alpha:2002,
    Author = {Beta Alpha},
    Note = {(= optional note)},
    Publisher = {Chicago},
    Title = {Book title},
    Year = {2002},
    edition = {2}}

@book{Gamma:2015,
    editor = {Delta Gamma and Zeta Epsilon},
    Publisher = {Berlin},
    Title = {Another book},
    Year = {2015}}

@article{Iota:1998,
    Author = {Kappa Iota},
    Journal = {journal name},
    Volume = {24},
    Pages = {11--18},
    Title = {article title},
    Year = {1998}}

@incollection{Ny:2018,
    Author = {Lambda Ny},
    Booktitle = {book title},
    Editor = {E. Ditor},
    Pages = {93--129},
    Publisher = {London},
    Title = {article title},
    Year = {2018}}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    Dies ist ein Testdokument zum Prüfen der bst-Datei.

    \footnote{Cf. \citet[12]{Alpha:2002}.}

    \footnote{Cf. \citet{Alpha:2002}.}

    \citet{Alpha:2002};
    \citet[13]{Gamma:2015};
    \citet[14]{Iota:1998};
    \citet[15]{Ny:2018}

    \bibliographystyle{test-companion}
    \bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Normally I would suggest to use `biblatex` for complex custom styles as these, **but** (1) even these days publishers can rarely accept `biblatex` submissions (see [Biblatex: submitting to a journal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864)) - except if they take the PDF directly -, furthermore (2) you seem to have gotten quite far with BibTeX already and lastly (3) the combined editor/year brackets looks like it would need quite a bit of code restructuring (not impossible, but a lot of work).

For the fun of it, here is a suggestion for a `biblatex` solution.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ext-authoryear, giveninits=true, uniquename=init, innamebeforetitle, articlein=false]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addslash}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{nametitledelim}{\addperiod\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{innametitledelim}{\addcomma\space}

% this is tricky, we want to merge the round brackets around
% the "ed."/"eds." and the year
% the idea is to only open the brackets in the editor string
% and the close it in the labelyear
% since editortype might also be used for editors of @in...
% types where this can't happen, we need a test
\newtoggle{bbx@editor@sortname}
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{bbx:editor}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseeditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }
    {\toggletrue{bbx@editor@sortname}%
     \usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\printnames{editor}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{editortypedelim}}%
        \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
     \usebibmacro{#1}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash
     \usebibmacro{labeltitle}%
     \setunit*{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}%
  \usebibmacro{date+extradate}%
  \togglefalse{bbx@editor@sortname}}
\makeatother

\DeclareFieldFormat{superedition}{\textsuperscript{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{%
  \iftoggle{bbx@editor@sortname}
    {\bibopenparen #1}
    {\mkbibparens{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{biblabeldate}{%
  \iftoggle{bbx@editor@sortname}
    {\addcomma\space
     \iffieldnum{edition}
       {\printfield[superedition]{edition}%
        \csgundef{abx@field@edition}}
       {}%
     #1\bibcloseparen}
    {\mkbibparens{%
       \iffieldnum{edition}
         {\printfield[superedition]{edition}%
          \csgundef{abx@field@edition}}
         {}%
       #1}}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}
%% tricky bit END

\DeclareFieldFormat{translatortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{translatortypedelim}{\addspace}

\renewbibmacro*{pubinstorg+location+date}[1]{%
  \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \iflistundef{#1}
    {\setunit*{\locdatedelim}}
    {\setunit*{\locpubdelim}}%
  \printlist{#1}%
  \setunit*{\pubdatedelim}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\ifentrytype{article}{\addcolon}{\addperiod}\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}

% some trickery is needed to get the parentheses right
% but biblatex already has a toggle to check for footnotes
\newtoggle{cbx:rsaparens}

\newbibmacro*{rsacite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}%
          \global\toggletrue{cbx:rsaparens}%
          \bibopenparen}}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}%
          \global\toggletrue{cbx:rsaparens}%
          \bibopenparen}}%
     \usebibmacro{rsacite:labeldate+extradate}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

\newbibmacro*{rsacite:labeldate+extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
       \iffieldnum{edition}
         {\printfield[superedition]{edition}}
         {}%
       \printlabeldateextra}}}

\newbibmacro*{rsacite:postnote}{%
  \iftoggle{blx@footnote}
    {\iftoggle{cbx:rsaparens}
       {\global\togglefalse{cbx:rsaparens}%
        \bibcloseparen}
       {}}
    {}%
  \iffieldundef{postnote}
    {}
    {\iftoggle{cbx:rsaparens}
       {\setunit{\postnotedelim}}
       {\setunit{\extpostnotedelim}}%
     \printfield{postnote}}%
  \iftoggle{cbx:rsaparens}
    {\global\togglefalse{cbx:rsaparens}%
     \bibcloseparen}
    {}}

\RegisterCiteDelims{outer}{rsacite}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\rsacite}[\mkouterrsacitedelims]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{rsacite}}
  {\iftoggle{cbx:rsaparens}
    {\global\togglefalse{cbx:rsaparens}%
     \bibcloseparen}
    {}%
   \multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{rsacite:postnote}}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\rsacites}[\mkouterrsacitedelims]
  {\rsacite}{\multicitedelim}

\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{rsa}{\rsacite}{\rsacites}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{autocite=rsa}

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{volcitepages}{\mknormrange{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Alpha:2002,
    Author = {Beta Alpha},
    Note = {(= optional note)},
    Publisher = {Chicago},
    Title = {Book title},
    Year = {2002},
    edition = {2}}

@book{Gamma:2015,
    editor = {Delta Gamma and Zeta Epsilon},
    Publisher = {Berlin},
    Title = {Another book},
    Year = {2015}}

@article{Iota:1998,
    Author = {Kappa Iota},
    Journal = {journal name},
    Volume = {24},
    Pages = {11--18},
    Title = {article title},
    Year = {1998}}

@incollection{Ny:2018,
    Author = {Lambda Ny},
    Booktitle = {book title},
    Editor = {E. Ditor},
    Pages = {93--129},
    Publisher = {London},
    Title = {article title},
    Year = {2018}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
  Lorem\footnote{\autocite[Cf.][12]{Alpha:2002}.}
  ipsum\footnote{\autocite[Cf.][]{Alpha:2002}.}
  dolor\footnote{\autocites(Cf.)()[12]{Alpha:2002}[380]{sigfridsson}.}
  sit\footnote{\autocite[Cf.][]{Alpha:2002,sigfridsson}.}
  amet.

  \autocite[12]{sigfridsson,worman}

  \autocites[12]{sigfridsson}[13]{worman}

  \autocite{Alpha:2002};
  \autocite[13]{Gamma:2015}
  \autocite[14]{Iota:1998};
  \autocite[15]{Ny:2018}

  \cite{sigfridsson}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]