# BibLaTeX name format

Tags: biblatex

I customized a bbx file for biblatex. I would like to have my references this way:

> [namepartprefix] [namepartfamily], [namepartgiveni] ...

Unfortinately, there are some spurious spaces before the name prefix (see attachments below), which I can't get rid of. I know that you have to take care of spaces at the end of a line in your source code. I have put some % signs right at the end of all related lines in my bbx file. Though, it does not work properly. Where is my mistake?

Plus, the name prefix is missing from the label names, that appear as citations. How can I insert the von/de etc part to the label?

---

bbx-text.tex

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=epicstructure,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{test-companion.bib}

\begin{document}


\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

test-companion.bib:

```
@Book{Alpha:2002,
  author    = {Beta von Alpha},
  year      = {2002},
  title     = {Book title},
  edition   = {2},
  note      = {(= optional note)},
  keywords  = {Walter,KAetGen},
  publisher = {Chicago},
}

@book{Gamma:2015,
    editor = {Delta Gamma and Zeta Epsilon and Sigma Rho},
    Publisher = {Berlin},
    Title = {Another book},
    Year = {2015},
    edition = {3}}

@article{Iota:1998,
    Author = {Kappa Iota},
    Journal = {journal name},
    Volume = {24},
    Pages = {11--18},
    Title = {article title},
    Year = {1998},
    keywords={KAetGen}}

@incollection{Ny:2018,
    Author = {Lambda Ny},
    Booktitle = {book title},
    Editor = {E. Ditor},
    Pages = {93--129},
    Publisher = {London},
    Title = {article title},
    Year = {2018}}
```

epicstructure.bbx:

```
\ProvidesFile{epicstructure.bbx}[2018/06/29 v1.0 biblatex bibliography style]

% Load the standard style to avoid copy-pasting unnecessary material
\RequireBibliographyStyle{authoryear}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{dashed=true}
\setlength{\bibparsep}{0em}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Eigene Änderungen                           %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Titel kursiv
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook,incollection]{title}{#1}


%%% Seitenzahlen in Zitaten ohne "S. " davor
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}

%%% Seiten bei article ohne "pp. "
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
\newcommand*{\bibpagespunctarticle}{\addcolon\addspace}
\newcommand*{\bibpagespunctincollinbook}{\adddot\addspace}


%%% "/" zwischen mehreren Autoren
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addslash}%
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addslash}%
\renewcommand*{\multilistdelim}{\addslash}%
\renewcommand*{\finallistdelim}{\addslash}%


\DeclareNameFormat{author}{%
  \ifblank{\namepartprefix}{}{\namepartprefix\addspace}%
  \namepartfamily%
    \ifblank{\namepartgiven}{}{\addcomma\addspace\namepartgiveni}%
  \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{liststop}}%
    {\multinamedelim}%
    {}%
}

\DeclareNameFormat{editor}{%
%  \ifblank{\namepartprefix}{}{\namepartprefix\addspace}%
  \namepartfamily%
    \ifblank{\namepartgiven}{}{\addcomma\addspace\namepartgiveni}%
  \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{liststop}}%
    {\multinamedelim}%
    {}%
}

\DeclareNameFormat{reversed}{%
  \ifblank{\namepartgiven}{}{\namepartgiveni\addspace}%
  \ifblank{\namepartprefix}{}{\namepartprefix\addspace}%
  \namepartfamily%
  \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{liststop}}%
    {\multinamedelim}%
    {}%
}

\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifboolexpr{%
    test \ifuseauthor%
    and%
    not test {\ifnameundef{author}}%
  }%
    {\printnames[author]{author}}%
    {}%
}

\renewbibmacro*{editor}{%
  \ifboolexpr{%
    test \ifuseeditor%
    and%
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}%
  }%
    {\printnames[author]{editor}}%
    {}%
}

\renewbibmacro*{author/editor}{%
  \ifboolexpr{%
    test \ifuseauthor%
    and%
    not test {\ifnameundef{author}}%
  }%
    {\usebibmacro{author}}%
    {\usebibmacro{editor}}%
}


\newbibmacro*{pages+article}{%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunctarticle}%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \newunit%
}


\renewcommand*{\bibnamedash}{%
    \rule[.5ex]{2em}{.15ex}.%
}


%%% ed./eds.
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  editor={ed\adddot},%
  editors={eds\adddot},%
  in={in}%
}

\newbibmacro*{editorstrng}{%
  \ifthenelse{\value{editor}>1}%\OR\ifandothers{editor}}%
    {\bibstring{editors}}%
    {\bibstring{editor}}%
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{edition}{%
  #1%
}

\newbibmacro*{editionsupscr}{%
  \iffieldundef{edition}%
    {}%
    {\textsuperscript{\printfield{edition}}}%
}

%%% (year)//(ed., year) -- article/book
\newbibmacro*{editor+edition+year}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}%
    {\mkbibparens{\usebibmacro{editionsupscr}\printfield{year}}}%
    {\mkbibparens{\usebibmacro{editorstrng}\addcomma\addspace\usebibmacro{editionsupscr}\printfield{year}}}%
}

%%% (year) -- inbook/incoll
\newbibmacro*{yearinbkcoll}{%
  \mkbibparens{\printfield{year}}%
}



\newbibmacro*{reversed:author}{%
    \printnames[reversed]{author}%
}

\newbibmacro*{reversed:editor}{%
    \printnames[reversed]{editor}\addspace\mkbibparens{\usebibmacro{editorstrng}}%
}


\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \biblcstring{in}\intitlepunct%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \iflistundef{publisher}%
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}}%
    {\setunit*{\addcolon\addspace}}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit%
}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
%  \setunit*{\adddot}%
  \iffieldundef{number}{}{(\printfield{number})}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
  \printfield{eid}%
}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Änderungen an Bibliography-Drivern          %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% article: FERTIG
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor}\addspace%
  \usebibmacro{editor+edition+year}\newunit\newblock%
  \usebibmacro{title}\addcomma%
  \newunit%
  \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
  \newunit%
  \usebibmacro{pages+article}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}



%%% book: FERTIG
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor}\addspace%
  \usebibmacro{editor+edition+year}\newunit\newblock%
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit%
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}%
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}%
    {}%
  \newunit%
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock%
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock%
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock%
  \printfield{note}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}



%%% inbook: work
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inbook}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author}\addspace%
  \usebibmacro{yearinbkcoll}\newunit\newblock%
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit\newblock%
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{reversed:editor}%
  \newunit\newblock%
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock%
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}\adddot%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \printfield{note}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}


\DeclareBibliographyAlias{incollection}{inbook}

\endinput
```

epicstructure.cbx:

```
\ProvidesFile{epicstructure.cbx}
[\abx@cbxid]

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{labeldateparts,uniquename,uniquelist,autocite=inline}

\renewcommand*{\iffinalcitedelim}{\iflastcitekey}

\newbool{cbx:parens}

\newbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}
       {\printnames[bibhyperref]{labelname}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

\newbibmacro*{citeyear}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\iffieldundef{labelyear}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

\newbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \ifnameundef{labelname}
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{%
          \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
          \printdelim{nonameyeardelim}\bibopenparen}%
        \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
          {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
          {}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
    {\printnames[bibhyperref]{labelname}%
     \setunit{%
       \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
       \printdelim{nameyeardelim}\bibopenparen}%
     \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
       {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
       {}%
     \usebibmacro{citeyear}}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:shorthand}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield{shorthand}}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:label}{%
  \iffieldundef{label}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield{label}}}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:labeldate+extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{editionsupscr}\printlabeldateextra}}}

\newbibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}{%
  \blx@warning{bibmacro 'cite:labelyear+extrayear' is deprecated.\MessageBreak
    Please use 'cite:labeldate+extradate'.\MessageBreak
    Using 'cite:labeldate+extradate' instead}%
  \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}

\newbibmacro*{textcite:postnote}{%
  \iffieldundef{postnote}
    {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
       {\bibcloseparen}
       {}}
    {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
       {\setunit{\postnotedelim}}
       {\setunit{\extpostnotedelim\bibopenparen}}%
     \printfield{postnote}\bibcloseparen}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\cite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{citeyear}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{citeyear}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcite}%[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcitetext}[\mkbibfootnotetext]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\smartcite}[\iffootnote\mkbibparens\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\textcite}
  {\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \iffirstcitekey
     {\setcounter{textcitetotal}{1}}
     {\stepcounter{textcitetotal}%
      \textcitedelim}%
   \usebibmacro{textcite}}
  {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
     {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
     {}}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthor}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}}
     {}%
   \printnames[bibhyperref]{labelname}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\citeauthor}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}}
     {}%
   \printnames[bibhyperref][1-1]{labelname}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeyear}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\printfield[bibhyperref]{year}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\citeyear}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\printfield[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{editionsupscr}year}\printfield{extradate}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\textcites}{\textcite}{}

\endinput
```

[image]

Comment: I'll have a closer look in a few minutes, but shouldn't you be fine with not redefining the `author` and `editor` formats and simply using the options `useprefix=true` and `giveninits=true` (and, I forgot, `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}`)?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I have just added your suggested options and the Alias. Now, I have the prefix part in the label. But still, there are those spurious spaces.
EDIT: Reference "von Alpha, B. ..." is now at the very end of the bibliography, as sorted by "_v_on".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is the use of `\ifblank` to check for empty name parts. Since the name parts are macros, you must use `\ifdefvoid`. `\ifblank` checks if a supplied string is blank, but `\ifdefvoid` checks if the supplied command sequence expands to a blank string (more or less).

So your name formats should read

```
\DeclareNameFormat{author}{%
  \ifdefvoid{\namepartprefix}{}{\namepartprefix\addspace}%
  \namepartfamily%
    \ifdefvoid{\namepartgiven}{}{\addcomma\addspace\namepartgiveni}%
  \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{liststop}}%
    {\multinamedelim}%
    {}%
}

\DeclareNameFormat{editor}{%
%  \ifdefvoid{\namepartprefix}{}{\namepartprefix\addspace}%
  \namepartfamily%
    \ifdefvoid{\namepartgiven}{}{\addcomma\addspace\namepartgiveni}%
  \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{liststop}}%
    {\multinamedelim}%
    {}%
}

\DeclareNameFormat{reversed}{%
  \ifdefvoid{\namepartgiven}{}{\namepartgiveni\addspace}%
  \ifdefvoid{\namepartprefix}{}{\namepartprefix\addspace}%
  \namepartfamily%
  \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{liststop}}%
    {\multinamedelim}%
    {}%
}
```

I believe, however, that

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\DeclareNameAlias{reversed}{given-family}
```

together with the options `useprefix=true,giveninits=true` would give the same result with less work.

---

Have a look at §4.11.7 *Using the Punctuation Tracker* of the `biblatex` manual. You should never have naked `\addspace`s in your bibliography driver. They should always be wrapped into a `\setunit` (or `\setunit*`).

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor}
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{editor+edition+year}
  \newunit\newblock%
  \usebibmacro{title}
  \setunit{\addcomma}%
  \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
  \newunit%
  \usebibmacro{pages+article}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}
```

A few other things.

`multinamedelim` and friends are context-sensitive now, so I would use

```
\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addslash}%
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}%
\DeclareDelimFormat{multilistdelim}{\addslash}%
\DeclareDelimAlias{finallistdelim}{multilistdelim}%
```

I think you can get rid of your redefinitions of `author` if you just issue the option `dashed=false`. For `editor` that might need a bit more work...

Never use `\mkbibparens` or other direct punctuation or formatting commands in bibmacros. Use `\DeclareFieldFormat` and `\printtext` instead (`\DeclareFieldFormat` is usually the better option, but sometimes one needs `\printtext`).

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{superedition}{%
  \ifinteger{#1}
    {}
    {\PackageWarning{epicstructure}{%
       Hang on! #1 does not look like an integer edition.\MessageBreak
       I will print it as superscript,\MessageBreak but it might look weird}}%
  \textsuperscript{#1}%
}

%%% (year)//(ed., year) -- article/book
\newbibmacro*{editor+edition+year}{%
  \printtext[parens]{%
    \ifnameundef{editor}%
      {}
      {\usebibmacro{editorstrng}%
       \setunit{\addcomma\space}}%
    \printfield[superedition]{edition}%
    \iflabeldateisdate
      {\printlabeldate}
      {\printfield{year}}% <- still don't like that...
  }%
}
```

For `yearinbkcoll` you could use the global option `date=year` and then

```
\newbibmacro*{yearinbkcoll}{%
  \iffieldundef{year}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{\printdate}}%
}
```

```
\newbibmacro*{reversed:editor}{%
    \printnames[reversed]{editor}%
    \setunit{\addspace}
    \printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{editorstrng}}%
}
```

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
%  \setunit*{\adddot}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
  \printfield{eid}%
}
```

Comment: Thanks again, @moewe. I would like to change the sorting. With your awesome answer, the `von` authors are listed under _v_ instead of under the first letter of the family name. Is there an easy way to fix this? Maybe a command, that I may comment out, if the publishers wants me to get back to the current settings someday.

Comment: @rsa-krypto Something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/440133/35864? If not, please ask a new question with an example and the expected output.

Comment: That's it. But the edition numbers are missing from in text citation. I'm very glad about your wide knowledge und quick help. I found your answer in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/438013/164672, but when compiling I get `,` after the authors' names in the in text citations...

Comment: @rsa-krypto Sorry, I don''t understand your point about the edition numbers. Of course the linked code does not have edition numbers in citations, but you only need to copy  the `usprefix` option and the `\DeclareSortingNamekeyTemplate` (and possibly the `begentry` definition). Those should not have an effect on the edition number in citations. I thought you already have those ready (I showed how that could work in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/438013/35864)?

Comment: If you have a problem with my code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/438013/35864 I suggest you ask a new question. It will be easier to discuss that with example code, pictures of the output and a longer explanation of what exactly you need to have changed.

Comment: I fixed it with some code snippets from your previous answers to my questions. It all does work now. I would like to read a bit further into the biblatex manual, and eventually put all the code from my .tex files to a .bbx and a .cbx file...