# Prefixes in author names in references and bibliography

Tags: biblatex, citing

I have a problem related to prefixes in the family names of researchers that I cite in my thesis. People whose names start with "van", "von, "den", "van der", and the like. I would want these to appear with the prefix in small letters in front of the family name in the reference in the running text, like (den Besten1983), then also in the same way in the bibliography, but not sorted after the prefix. So "den Besten, Hans" should be listed under B. With my current settings, I get (Besten1983) in the text, and "Besten, Hans den" in the bibliography. I have tried enclosing "den Besten" in curly brackets in the BibTex source (I use Jabref), like this {den Besten}, Hans. This gives the right result in the reference, but lists the name as "den Besten, Hans" under D in the bibliography.

Source in JabRef:
 author =    {den Besten, Hans},

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage [T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}
\begin{document}
Blabla \cite{denBesten1983}. 
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several ways to do this (see for example [Biblatex handling of Dutch "van" prefix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/226893/35864)), but with a current `biblatex` I would do the following

1. Set the `useprefix=true` option. This tells `biblatex` to treat "den Boer" as the family name, always printing "den Boer" and sorting under "d".
2. Change the sorting so names are sorted by their `family` component first and only then by the `prefix`. Hence, contrary to what `useprefix=true` from point 1 would dictate, "den Boer" sorts under "B".
3. Modify the bibliography so that the prefix is not capitalised. (Since each bib item issues `\bibsentence` by default at a very late stage after the `\AtEveryBibitem` hook is processed, the cleanest solution I could find is to hook into the `begentry` bibmacro.)

```
\documentclass[12]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-comp, useprefix]{biblatex}

\DeclareSortingNamekeyTemplate{
  \keypart{
    \namepart{family}
  }
  \keypart{
    \namepart{prefix}
  }
  \keypart{
    \namepart{given}
  }
  \keypart{
    \namepart{suffix}
  }
}

\renewbibmacro{begentry}{\midsentence}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{besten,
  author  = {Hans den Besten},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  date    = {1980},
}
@book{boer,
  author  = {Hans de Boer},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  date    = {1980},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{besten}\nocite{boer,baez/article,cicero,worman,sigfridsson} 
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I seem to be doing something wrong. If I just add the "useprefix" option to the biblatex package, and then copy everything from "\DeclareSortingNamekeyTemplate" to \end{filecontents} into the preamble, I get the error message "Undefined control sequence" / DeclareSortingNamekeyTemplate"  ... This is probably my fault, what am I doing wrong? Does the filecontents package rewrite BibLatex sources? I suppose I should change "\ref.jobname" for my own .bib-file?

Comment: @EspenJK You are using an outdated version of `biblatex`. You should consider updating (as always, an update shortly before a deadline might be ill-advised, updates always have the potential to break stuff). In old versions `\DeclareSortingNamekeyTemplate` was called `\DeclareSortingNamekeyScheme`, so you could replace the new name with the old one, maybe it works for you then.

Comment: I trid that, still gives the same error message. I will of course update biblatex as soon as I have handed in my thesis. Is there something else I could be doing wrong? Mind, what I have done, concretely, is to add the "useprefix" option and then copy-paste everything in your code from \DeclareSorting... to \end{filecontents} I did not, for instance, change \jobname.bib into my own filename. Basically because I don't know exactly what this package is doing!

Comment: @EspenJK If you replaced `\DeclareSortingNamekeyTemplate` with `\DeclareSortingNamekeyScheme` the error message can't be the same because there is no `\DeclareSortingNamekeyTemplate` any more. `\DeclareSortingNamekeyScheme` was introduced in version 3.3 back in March 2016, it was renamed to \DeclareSortingNamekeyTemplate` in version 3.8 in November 2017. If your system is older than that, you can try https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/226893/35864. ...

Comment: ... The `filecontents` is just to produce a `.bib` file the MWE can use, it is not needed in your actual document. Only copy the bit up to `\renewbibmacro{begentry}{\midsentence}`.

Comment: @moeve, what I meant is that the error message is of the same type, although of course now it reads: "Undefined control sequence.\ DeclareSortingNamekeyScheme" I also removed the filecontents bit...

Comment: I followed your link and adopted the solution there, which seems to work, although it prints the prefix with a capital letter in the bibliograpghy : Den Besten, Hans. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @EspenJK Even with `\renewbibmacro{begentry}{\midsentence}`?

Comment: @moeve, sorry, I was a bit quick. With \renewbibmacro{begentry}{\midsentence} eveything works perfectly. Thanks again, you deserve a mention in the Acknowledgements part of my thesis. :)

Comment: This works well for `\cite`, `\textcite`, `\parencite` etc., but not for `\footcite`, where the `prefix` is still printed with an upper-case initial in the footnote. Can anything be done about this?

Comment: `\xpatchbibmacro{name:family}{\MakeCapital}{}{}{}`  and  `\AtBeginBibliography{\renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{\midsentence #1}}`  seem to be having the effect i am looking for.

Comment: @svenper By default `biblatex` capitalises the beginning of a `\footcite` like the beginning of a sentence, hence the prefix comes out with a capital letter. It's the same for *ibidem* in a footnote citation, which comes out as "Ibid." if it is the first word. You can completely turn off this behaviour with `\renewcommand{\bibfootnotewrapper}[1]{#1\addperiod}`. If you want only your name prefixes to ignore capitalisation you need to remove the `\MakeCapital` from `name:family-given` and `name:family` (I wouldn't redefine `\mkbibnameprefix` for that).

Comment: Thank you! It seems so much more complex than BibTeX sometimes :-).