# \addbibresource yields undefined control sequence with Beamer

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, undefined

I am making a handout with beamer, and I get the error message `undefined control sequence` when I add the `\addbibresource` command to the preamble. This seems to happen only when document class is beamer, not in articles. I have MikTex 2.9 and I use Winedt 10.

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[14pt, handout]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{xyling}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper, border shrink=5mm]
\addbibresource{ref.bib}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Some text \cite{EKP2018}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\addbibresource` is a `biblatex` command. You need to load `biblatex` yourself. `beamer` does not load it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\addbibresource` is a `biblatex` command and therefore only available if `biblatex` is loaded.

`beamer` does not load `biblatex` automatically (and neither does any other package in the preamble of the MWE), hence the command comes out as undefined. The solution is to load `biblatex` explicitly, for example with

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric]{biblatex}
```

The error can also be reproduced for me with `article` instead of `beamer` as document class, which makes sense because `article` (like most normal document classes) does not load `biblatex` either.

Comment: +1, I would add the `bibTeX` way too in case that (possibly) the OP just didn't know

Comment: @koleygr I'd like to wait for a response by the OP first. I try to keep my answers focussed on the main issue of the question and I'm not sure if adding a paragraph about BibTeX bibliographies would really be relevant. FWIW the OP seems to be an occasional `biblatex` user (cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/440133/35864), so chances are they really want `biblatex`.

Comment: I would add another vote if possible, since I never thought yo find out if the OP was a `biblatex` user... I just thought form the question that he/she didn't knew about the cases for adding bibliography... and so, I focused to that problem that I thought it was the basic problem of the OP...

Comment: Sorry late feedback: @moewe is right, it was quity simply a matter of calling biblatex explicitly, which I also normally do, I had simply forgotten it. Yes, I normally use biblatex on biber.