# Proper handling (ordering) of the Dutch/Portuguese order in BibLaTeX

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to set the proper ordering of a Bibliography in Portuguese using names with particles (de Souza, d'Alessandro, dos Santos, ...).

The general idea is that prefixes should be used as part of the total name every time they are written, but for the order in the bibliographies, the names should be sorted with the prefixes removed. This is, in general, called `dutch-ordering` because a large percentage of the population has particles in their names and using them for the order would be a mess.

I can get the names written properly, but not the proper order in the Biblio.

This is my current MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{orm-d,
  author = {d'Ormesson, Jean},
  title = {Title: dumb apostrophe},
  date = {2015},
}
@book{hak,
  author = {al-Hakim, Tawfik},
  title = {Title},
  date = {2015},
}
@book{khaled,
  author = {el Shadad, Khaled},
  title = {Title},
  date = {2015},
}
@book{deF,
  author = {de Faria, Rafael},
  title = {Title},
  date = {2015},
}
@book{dosS,
  author = {dos Santos, Raul},
  title = {Title},
  date = {2015},
}
@book{dlm,
  author = {de la Martinière, III, Gérard},
  title = {Title},
  date = {2015},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{portuges}

\usepackage[
        backend=biber,
        style=authoryear,
        useprefix=true,
            ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\section*{Text}
\cite{hak, orm-d, khaled, deF, dosS, dlm}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The correct order should be is:

```
De Faria, Rafael (2015). Title.
al-Hakim, Tawfik (2015). Title.
De la Martinière III, Gérard (2015). Title.
d’Ormesson, Jean (2015). Title.
Dos Santos, Raul (2015). Title.
El Shadad, Khaled (2015). Title.
```

I have seen a few solutions for BibTeX but not for BibLaTeX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the code from my answer to [Prefixes in author names in references and bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/440133/35864).

This already takes care of almost anything in your example except for *d'Ormesson*. BibTeX's name parsing rules (that are emulated by Biber) will always parse this as a single (family name) unit. In order to split the `d'` from the `Ormesson` you will have to change the input to the (admittedly not-quite-correct-looking)

```
@book{orm-d,
  author = {d' Ormesson, Jean},
  title  = {Title: dumb apostrophe},
  date   = {2015},
}
```

`biblatex` will automatically drop the unnecessary space in the output thanks to `\DeclarePrefChars`, see https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/346.

In total we get

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=authoryear,
  useprefix=true,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareSortingNamekeyTemplate{
  \keypart{
    \namepart{family}
  }
  \keypart{
    \namepart{prefix}
  }
  \keypart{
    \namepart{given}
  }
  \keypart{
    \namepart{suffix}
  }
}

\renewbibmacro{begentry}{\midsentence}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{orm-d,
  author = {d' Ormesson, Jean},
  title  = {Title: dumb apostrophe},
  date   = {2015},
}
@book{hak,
  author = {al-Hakim, Tawfik},
  title  = {Title},
  date   = {2015},
}
@book{khaled,
  author = {el Shadad, Khaled},
  title  = {Title},
  date   = {2015},
}
@book{deF,
  author = {de Faria, Rafael},
  title  = {Title},
  date   = {2015},
}
@book{dosS,
  author = {dos Santos, Raul},
  title  = {Title},
  date   = {2015},
}
@book{dlm,
  author = {de la Martinière, III, Gérard},
  title  = {Title},
  date   = {2015},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\section*{Text}
\cite{hak, orm-d, khaled, deF, dosS, dlm}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: de Faria, Rafael (2015). Title.//al-Hakim, Tawfik (2015). Title.//de la Martinière III, Gérard (2015). Title.//d’Ormesson, Jean (2015). Title: dumb apostrophe.//dos Santos, Raul (2015). Title.//el Shadad, Khaled (2015). Title.]

Comment: Works like a charm. Many thanks.