# Positions of the words van and de using APA-style and biblatex

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I am writing a text in Portuguese and I must cite a book whose some authors are Bernardo van Raij and João Carlos de Andrade. These names must be shown in the bibliography section as  Raij, B van and Andrade, J. C. de
I am using the APA style and biblatex package. My "best" output was Raij, B. v., Andrade, J. C. d.  for the respective entries in the author field of bib file:
author    = {Raij, B. van and Andrade, J  C. de and Heitor Cantarella and José Antônio Quaggio},
Any trick? Thank you.

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/440150/273733)

Comment: It seems that those solutions work fine for authoryear style and not for the APA one. Am I wrong? Excuse me for my ignorance.

Answer (score 1):

A correct way to input these names would be

```
author    = {Bernardo van Raij and João Carlos de Andrade},
```

With this input you can get the desired output if you set the option `useprefix=false,`.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, useprefix=false]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{raij,
  author    = {Bernardo van Raij and João Carlos de Andrade},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1972},
  publisher = {Monthy \& Co.},
  location  = {London},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,raij}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Raij, B. van, & Andrade, J. C. de. (1972). A theory on brontosauruses. Monthy & Co.]

Comment: Awesome moewe! Thank you very much!