# embedding overleaf dokument into website

Tags: html, python, embedding, overleaf, javascript

is it possible to dynamically embed a overleaf document into a simple (bootstraping-theme, html5) website using the "Read Only Link" ? either with embedding the latest version of the document as a pdf or (better) make an output of the latex-code framed by html; or maybe (surely) there is an other way with javascript or python?

Comment: I think this is really off-topic here and would be better asked elsewhere: either on Overleaf or on a site specialising in HTML etc. It doesn't have anything to do with TeX.

Comment: perhaps, but my question is also: is there a general solution for embedding a more complex latex-code into a webpage

Comment: If by that you mean converting LaTeX to HTML, then that's a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39309/convert-latex-to-html or perhaps https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68916/convert-latex-to-mathjax-html

Comment: Your comment is about embedding code to HTML. This would be off-topic here. Nevertheless, you can add code (but not its' execution) of several programming languages using [GeSHi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeSHi) on HTML pages. And you can use the overleaf API to open a new overleaf project with the code (examples pages, that already use it, are, e.g., http://golatex.de or http://texwelt.de).

Comment: A deleted answer suggested `htlatex`, but notes that it is not an automagical embedding. (It says it is not 'automaical', but I assume that should be 'automagical'.) However, that is for producing HTML from LaTeX code and I don't think that is what you're trying to do here. If that is what you're trying to do, see the links @TorbjørnT. suggested above.

Comment: @לאהפּאַסטעך Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @SebastianNielsen: no.