# Is this a good use case for LaTeX?

Tags: pdf, compiling, latex2html

I'm trying to understand if LaTeX is a good choice for my use case(s).  I don't know LaTeX and am having a hard time finding if these things are all possible, or maybe it is more a compiler question?

- I'm trying to create a document for a software product that gets rebranded depending on the customer we sell it to.
- Need a text based documentation so multiple developers can update it and it can get merged together without issue in version control.
- The document needs to support themes - different colors and styles (look and feel)
- The document needs to be able to use variables that can be replaced when converted.  e.g. {customer name} -> compile to PDF -> Walmart
- The document should support either conditionals, or someway to have a "customer style" that can be attached at compile time.  Like:  `compile latex --customer:walmart.style`
- Needs to output PDF, optionally also output HTML.

In searching the internet, I keep coming back to LaTeX, but I'm having a hard time differentiating what is the documentation language providing vs the compiler.

So, can this be done with LaTeX?  If so, do I need a particular compiler? If not, any suggestion on a product that might provide something like this?

#### EDIT 1

Wow, this is a very active and helpful community, thanks for all the responses!

Here is an example today of what is used, but it is not meeting the needs:

1. Developers/Humans write the document using markdown

   ```
   <snip>
   that help your institution function more effectively.

   ![](md_images/media/image2.png){ width=90% }


   # Hardware Requirements

   1.  Single Tier system (windows + CIE + SQL) - recommended for low-medium volume sites:

       **BASE**  (supports up to 4 Channels high volume):
   <snip>
   ```

   This is then run through pandoc with MiKTeX and a `.css` style to produce a `.doc`, HTML, and PDF. However, it can't handle variables or conditionals very well, and the look and feel needs to be done all in CSS which can add alot of overhead, especially trying to go across the output file types.

   This will produce an output like:

   [image]
2. Would like to have some type of system that works similar to this (which does not work today, it's just photoshopped):

   ```
   # Hardware Requirements for {customer}
   ```

   would output something like:

   [image]

#### EDIT 2:

Trying to address the hold question:

- Does LaTeX support branding?  For example, look & feel, replaceable
  variables and conditional text.
- Can LaTeX be outputted to PDF, HTML and `.docx` using a single base document + a branding style sheet?

Comment: 1. yes,
2. yes,
3. yes,
4. gut feeling says "yes",
5. see 4.,
6. yes. see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39309/convert-latex-to-html

Comment: do you have an example of data and required output style?

Comment: Have you seen Sphinx?

Comment: LaTeX is great for human-authored documents, e.g. it has code for implementing things that would be cumbersome for a human (automatic section numbering, sorted bibliography, easily updated references to other sections, consistent typesetting, …). But for things that aren't human-authored, I would recommend *not* using LaTeX directly, except for the typesetting (to get a PDF). Make your own system that collects the data and processes the conditionals etc., and have it populate either a HTML template (to generate the HTML file) or (La)TeX template (to generate the PDF file).

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I assume the developers who need to be able to edit it are human beings, so I take it you're suggesting that the actual documentation part not be LaTeX either, though I'm not clear why as this seems just the kind of case where it is better for developers to write e.g. `\section{This bit}` rather than `5. This bit` or whatever. But I fear I have misunderstood?

Comment: I would think handling the core of the documentation as LaTeX, but doing the wrapping with other tools, as @ShreevatsaR suggests, would probably be the most straightforward approach. While you could (almost) certainly cook-up something for the whole thing in LaTeX, I can't see any good reason to do it this way and would expect it to be less flexible and harder to maintain and use than a combo solution. This is unless you'd be prepared to accept a different workflow than the one you specify. If you could use a different workflow, then the answer would likely be different.

Comment: If you wanted to try an all-LaTeX approach, I'd work with LaTeX rather than trying to fit LaTeX into a non-LaTeX-shaped hole. For example, you might use a thin wrapper file for each different customer, which would then pull in the common configuration and the documentation itself. However, then you'd be saying `compiler weaver-street.tex` or `compiler woolworths.tex` rather than compiling the same `.tex` file with different arguments. But `weaver-street.tex` and `woolworths.tex` would include only the Weaver Street- and Woolworths-specific stuff - the rest would all be in another file(s).

Comment: @cfr I meant things like: • For export to other formats, I'd have to implement generating e.g. "5. This bit". Might as well use that in the TeX document, for consistency just in case. • If characters like `&$%\~` appear in content, it would be cleaner to have the export-to-TeX code handle “escaping” them, than to type `\textasciitilde` (etc.) into the original data. • Conditionals are easier for developers to handle in their preferred languages. • I may want to reorder or vary data with different “themes”, etc. This can get messy inside TeX; is cleaner in templating systems designed for this.

Comment: @cfr I think in practice what you're recommending and what I'm thinking of would end up being the same. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The question is a little nebulous and open ended but one approach that you could use would be to have separate "style" files for each customer and then have the main file dynamically load the appropriate style when you compile the document.

To be more explicit, suppose that your main document file was the somewhat artificial `main.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[description]{
  font=\sffamily\bfseries\color{DodgerBlue},
  labelwidth=\textwidth
}
\newif\ifPaying

\expandafter\usepackage\expandafter{\customer}% load customer data

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
  \item[Customer name] \customerName
  \item[Address] \address
  \ifPaying\item[Account] \accountNumber\fi
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

and that have two customer files `customer1.sty`

```
\newcommand\customerName{Alfred}
\newcommand\address{Mexico}
\Payingtrue
\newcommand\accountNumber{10309-190123-9}
```

and `customer2.sty`

```
\newcommand\customerName{Julie}
\newcommand\address{Spain}
\Payingfalse
```

Then you can use the following trick to dynamically set the customer to   `customer1` when you compile the document:

> pdflatex -jobname=main "\def\customer{customer1}\input{main}"

With the files above this will produce a PDF file `main.pdf`:

[image]

Similarly, the command

> pdflatex -jobname=main "\def\customer{customer2}\input{main}"

will produce a variant of the "same" document for `customer2`:

[image]

By the way, you could also use something like

> pdflatex -jobname=main-customer2 "\def\customer{customer2}\input{main}"

to produce the customised PDF file name of `main-customer2.pdf`, or anything you liked.

In the examples above I have used colour and the the conditional `\ifPaying` because these features were mentioned in the question but the example is a little contrived and I would probably not use code like this in practice (for example, instead of using `\ifPaying` I would probably use `\iscsdef{accountNumber}` from the [etoolbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package). Please consider adding a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) to your question to better illustrate what you really want.

Conversion to HTML is potentially problematic. If your documents are "not very complicated" this should be straightforward but complicated documents are always harder to convert. Either way, from LaTeX I recommend using [tex4ht](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tex4ht). This is highly configurable and can almost certainly do what you want but the flip-side of being highly configurable is that you need to learn how to configure it. Using something like sphinx, as suggested in the comments, or writing code to dynamically generate latex or html output might be a better approach. It's not possible to recommend any particular approach without more concrete details of what you need and what your customer data looks like and how it is stored and accessed.

Comment: Thank you this is an extremely helpful example to help me understand if/how to use LaTeX for these use cases!