# Latex to not PDF on Windows

Tags: latex2html

Is it possible to export Latex to non pdf format? HTML, rtf, doc, ePub, odt will be good.

I read about that, but it seems obsolete now. Any new solutions for such important thing?

My OS is Windows.

Comment: `Pandoc` and `TeX4ht`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert LaTeX to HTML](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39309/convert-latex-to-html)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there seems to be [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/installing.html) see relevant [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/544100/the-table-of-contents-toc-is-not-appearing-in-the-docx-file-or-the-epub-file)