# Convert .tex to .html on Overleaf

Tags: pdf, overleaf, conversion, html

Ok, so I know this *might* seem the same as [David Carlisle question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39309/convert-latex-to-html). However it differs in one key way. I want to know how to generate an html output *within* Overleaf. Which is not referenced anywhere on David Carlisle post. I have, so far been following the instructions on "Better Books with LaTeX" specifically [this](https://www.lode.de/blog/converting-latex-to-html/) section. So far I ve done the following:

1. Changed my compiler to pdfLaTeX.
2. Made sure my code works with pdfLaTeX.
3. Added a latexmkrc file to my main directory.
4. Added the following code to the latexmkrc file:

```
$pdflatex = "htlatex %S \"htlatex.cfg,MyFonts,NoFonts\" \"\" \"\" -shell-escape > output.txt; pdflatex -synctex=1 %O %S";
```

However, according to the guide after this step, if I recompile I should get a new file in my directory with my document in html format. This is not happening. I have a particular interest in doing this inside Overleaf, but have so far, been unsuccessful at finding other documentation/guides on how to to this. So if additionally to knowing how to complete the process described above, anyone knows of some place where there are guides on how to do such thing I would appreciate it greatly.

Comment: You should ask overleaf support. In the meantime, take a look here: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/testing-html-export-with-tex4ht

Comment: overleaf do document how to do this https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/testing-html-export-with-tex4ht/rqcknjvwyyry

Comment: @DG' ooh you just beat me to it:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle \o/

Comment: another option: https://www.kodymirus.cz/overleaf-html-sample/main.html