# How to write LaTeX in browsers (in other words HTML)?

Tags: html, mathjax, mathml

I know it is a dumb question because there is MathJax and MathML. But lots of people has said that MathJax also have MathML support. And in https://artofproblemsolving.com, I found that MathJax doesn't support everything in LaTeX. But in Art of Problem Solving website, we can use latex when posting anything. So, how do they support LaTeX? Is there any library that allows to use almost everything in LaTeX in HTML pages?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! `\LaTeX` or LaTeX ...

Comment: this question is probably off topic, but can you give a link to a site that you say allows any latex, do you mean you can use `\section{Something}`  and it makes an HTML heading?

Comment: Are you wanting to convert tex in realtime to html, or are you wanting to take an existing tex document and turn it into html?  There are many options for the latter: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39309/107497

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at https://artofproblemsolving.com/texer

The site has several mechinsms, mathjax for embedding math-only math expresssions in a web page but also a full rendering of arbitrary latex to pdf, this is running texlive 2021 on a server (like overleaf or learnlatex.org) and showing PDF not embedding math in an HTML page.

[image]