# How to make a personal website in LaTeX?

Tags: questionnaire

This is probably not a very wise question, but does anyone have any idea how websites like https://rossprogram.org/ are made in TeX? I'm looking to make a personal website in LaTeX, but I don't know if it is even possible. Thanks!

Comment: 1. Who says it's made in TeX?  2. TeX is primarily used to output a pdf (or dvi, back in the day).  "make a personal website in LaTeX" is possible, but not the intended use.  It'd be far easier to learn enough html to make the site.  Why are you wanting to do this?

Comment: That site uses the Computer Modern font which is the default in TeX, but using that font doesn't require LaTeX. 

You could write a site in LaTeX and compile it to HTML with [TeX4ht/htlatex](https://tug.org/tex4ht/) if you wanted, but it's unclear why you would; is there something more specific you're after?

Comment: The source shows all:  view-source:https://rossprogram.org/

Comment: My website, https://loopspace.mathforge.org/, *is* written in LaTeX and converted to html via my Internet class, https://github.com/loopspace/latex-to-internet

Comment: Good tools to do mathematical typesetting in LaTeX include MathML and MathJax. You could also render equations to a standalone SVG and embed that. If you just want a version of Computer Modern that you can use on the Web, you might try New Computer Modern or Latin Modern.

Answer (score 12):

Ross's website does not use TeX to create a website (I doubt you could use a .tex file to display a website anyways - though I may be incorrect in this regard). If you look at the footer of the site, you can see it says that it was created using Jekyll with Minimal Mistakes (which I presume to be some sort of add-on or theme for Jekyll).

If you meant how you can get your website to look like a LaTeX document, you could simply just spend some time writing a .css file that accomplishes this. Alternatively, you may want to check out this project: [LaTex.css](https://latex.vercel.app) which styles your HTML as a LaTeX-esque document. It seems quite easy to set up as well.

Comment: Its a theme: https://mademistakes.com/work/minimal-mistakes-jekyll-theme/

Answer (score 5):

That site isn’t actually created with LaTeX. It appears to be created using [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com). Setting up a website to use Computer Modern (or, more likely a Unicode-based variant thereof), however, is off topic for tex.stackexchange.

There are tools like [LaTeX2HTML](https://www.latex2html.org) that will convert LaTeX into HTML pages with varying degrees of fidelity and usability, not to mention tools like [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org) that simplify the use of LaTeX-like mathematics in HTML documents. A bit of [googling](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=latex%20to%20html) can turn up some useful further information.

Answer (score 2):

This answer might be off-topic compared to typical TeX.SE answers. I think the website doesn't really use TeX/LaTeX for generating the text. I think it displays ordinary text as LaTeX font (I am not taking about mathematical formulas as they are usually generated by [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org) or [KaTeX](https://katex.org)). Computer Modern, the typical LaTeX font, is used in the website via CSS. I tweaked [dreampulse](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/dreampulse/computer-modern-web-font@master/example.html)'s solution and attached this minimal html code. Create a file and ensure it is of type .html, paste the code, save it and then open it using your browser. The result should be:

[image: Output]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>LaTeX Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/dreampulse/computer-modern-web-font@master/fonts.css">
  <style>
        * {font-family: "Computer Modern Serif", sans-serif; }
    
        /* Comment here: fonts to use are
        "Computer Modern Serif",
        "Computer Modern Bright",
        "Computer Modern Concrete",
        "Computer Modern Sans",
        "Computer Modern Serif",
        "Computer Modern Typewriter"
        */
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<p>Normal text <strong>bold text</strong> <i>italicized text</i></p>
</body>
</html>
```

To briefly explain, the line `* {font-family: "Computer Modern Serif", sans-serif; }` means change the font of all html tags to `Computer Modern Serif`.

**Disclaimer: please ensure that the license is appropriate for your use.**

Answer (score 1):

I am on my phone (= I keep it short) and just want to add my two cents :).

1. Maybe **pandoc** could be used for that.
2. Maybe **TEX4ht** is an option.

Comment: Well there's a full list [pdftex - Convert LaTeX to HTML - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39309/convert-latex-to-html)

Comment: @user202729 That's very good, thanks.