# When compiling with make4ht, how to avoid generation of intermediate files that are corrupting the index of version control?

Tags: html, make4ht

I'm using make4ht as a replacement of the old htlatex to convert a tex file into HTML (see this post for detail: [Is the htlatex tool of the latest texlive broken?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/656315/is-the-htlatex-tool-of-the-latest-texlive-broken?noredirect=1#comment1635392_656315))

With the following command, the html is able to be generated successfully under `out/html`:

```
make4ht -d "out/html" "Main.tex"
```

Unfortunately, I found the following files under the current directory:

```
Main.4ct
Main.4tc
Main.aux
Main.css
Main.dvi
Main.html
Main.idv
Main.lg
Main.log
Main.tmp
Main.xref
```

Since these files are not under `out`, they are now corrupting my version control, is there a ways to avoid this?

Comment: htlatex is not "defunct", but make4ht is easier to use.

Comment: you are right, edited

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a method for cleaning the build files discussed on page 5 of the [make4ht documentation](https://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/support/make4ht/make4ht-doc.pdf). It involves using the `-m clean` option. This is done in a separate call to the command. To chain it together with compilation, you could do:

```
make4ht -d "out/html" "Main.tex" && make4ht -m clean "Main.tex"
```

However, personally I would prefer to use other methods to avoid "corrupting" your version control. A good version control system should have built in mechanisms for that. For example, for git you can add those filenames your [`.gitignore` file](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) so that, well, git ignores them.

This way you don't have to constantly regenerate temporary files.

Comment: Thanks a lot! problem solved. I have to admit that it is a weird design tho

Comment: @tribbloid this is just normal design of latex. You need temporary files for various features. It is not reasonable to delete them between particular compilations, it is best to use .gitignore if you don't want them to interfere with git