# How to print or convert HTML document into PDF using LaTeX

Tags: conversion, html

I written one XSD schema, I documented that schema using xmlpad, It generates the HTML documentation automatically for that XSD schema. Now I want to generate a PDF document for that HTML document. I thought to convert the HTML document to LaTeX and I am using `pdflatex` to generate the PDF document. But I don't know how to convert a HTML document to LaTeX? Is there any open source tool? Can anyone suggest a tool or any other way? I need to convert a HTML document to PDF.

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea. Every browser's "print" button can convert HTML to PDF directly, without the need to go through latex.

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3079/how-do-i-convert-html-to-latex

Comment: I used the open-source-project [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org) several times already for directly converting HTML-code to PDF. I don't see any advantage in doing this with LaTex, to be honest. However, TCPDF requires a local PHP-installation or a webserver to run on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about LaTeX, but with ConTeXt MkIV, you can parse XML. For an example of parsing HTML, see the [My Way](http://dl.contextgarden.net/myway/tas/) by Thomas Schmitz

Answer (score 2):

You could use pandoc to convert the HTML to LaTeX and then generate the PDF from the output.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the solution from **dfc**! This is based on his suggestion.

You can directly use `pandoc` to convert HTML to PDF, e.g. convert google-cpp-styleguide.html to PDF documents:

`pandoc cppguide.html -o cppguide.pdf`

However, I prefer to firstly convert to LaTeX via `pandoc`, then edit `.tex` file to fit my desires (since the default PDF generated above is using `article` class in LaTeX, I prefer to tune the page layout to save papers). For example,

`pandoc -s cppguide.html -o cppguide.tex`

then use your favorite LaTeX (e.g. **AucTeX**) to edit it as you want, and `pdflatex` it.

Refer to http://pandoc.org/demos.html for pandoc usage demos.

Comment: You can specify a custom preamble for Pandoc-generated LaTeX files, so there's probably no need to edit the resulting file.