# How to convert HTML markup into LaTeX markup?

Tags: pdftex, conversion, html, markup

I have one input file which will be used for LaTeX and HTML (Java program). Input file has HTML markups like

```html
<b></b> for bold.
<li></li> for list.
```

How can I convert above markup into LaTeX markup while generating pdf?

Comment: Consider reading [How do I convert HTML to LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3079/5764)

Comment: I don't want to convert HTML into latex but jsut need to modify some text.

Comment: So you want LaTeX to convert (say) `<b>hello</b>` to `{\bfseries hello}` or `\textbf{hello}` within a certain piece of your code? That is, keep the code HTML but interpret it in a different way? Is this because you don't want to change the HTML mark-up to LaTeX, I guess, to easily transition between the two formats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try sed?

```
cat test 
<b>Bold text</b>. Regular text, <i>italics</i>, <tt>teletype</tt>, regular.
Nested: <b>Bold <i>bold italics</i> again bold</b> 

sed -e 's|<b>\(.*\)</b>|\\textbf{\1}|g' -e 's|<i>\(.*\)</i>|\\textit{\1}|g' -e 's|<tt>\(.*\)</tt>|\\texttt{\1}|g' test
\textbf{Bold text}. Regular text, \textit{italics}, \texttt{teletype}, regular.
Nested: \textbf{Bold \textit{bold italics} again bold}
```

Comment: @ Eddy_Em your answer is very useful, can we convert <ol><li></li></ol> also into latex markup.

Comment: Yes: `sed -e 's|<ol>\(.*\)</ol>|\\begin{enumerate}\n\1\\end{enumerate}|g' -e 's|<li>\([^<]*\)</li>|\t\\item \1\n|g'` but if there could be other tags between `<li></li>` regexp would be more complex. Another variant is to remove all `</li>` and substitute by `/item` only `<li>`. Also this construction will not work for nested lists.

Comment: Above script does not convert ul or ol into \itemize

Comment: `echo "<ul><li>1a</li><li>2a</li></ul>" | sed -e 's|<ul>|\\begin{enumerate}|g' -e 's|</ul>|\\end{enumerate}|g' -e 's|<li>|\\item |g' -e 's|</li>||g'`
`\begin{enumerate}\item 1a\item 2a\end{enumerate}`