# Import Simulink figures in LaTeX

Tags: graphics, diagrams

I am writing my Thesis report using LaTeX. I have to explain about a few models that I created in Simulink in my report. I do not know how to import these Simulink models into LaTeX. Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: I think you have two options: (1) make a snapshot and insert the picture in your `LaTeX` file or (2) export the Simulink model to HTML, then convert to `LaTeX`: see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3079/) for this last step.

Answer (score 7):

You can do the following; I use Matlab 2013, but I suspect that can also be done in older versions.

1. Go to *File >> Print*, then click on *Print*.
2. Under *Device option*, write `-dpdf`.
3. Under *Send to*, you have a choice of two radio buttons; select *File*.
4. Press *Print*; a dialog box will prompt you to choose a path for the file.

Then, in LaTeX, simply use `\includegraphics` from the `graphicx` package to insert the pdf you have just saved.

**Note**: In my experience, most people tend to insert Simulink diagrams as raster-graphics images of dimensions so small that the model is illegible, even when you zoom in on it. That problem is easily obviated by using a vector-graphics format (e.g. pdf), which I urge you to do.

Comment: Take note that converting the block to pdf gives you some white spaces around the figure.

Comment: @HasanZakeri Yes. That's what I was trying to fix. Matlab/Simulink doesn't seem to offer much flexibility in this regard. The only workaround is to modify the paper size option in the Print window.

Comment: Or remove the surrounding white space with external tools, eg. ghostscript :)

Comment: I sometimes use Adobe illustrator to crop pdf files.

Answer (score 2):

First, save your Simulink model as a figure using Matlab command:

> saveas(h,'filename.ext')

or

> saveas(h,'filename','format')

following the directions in
[this MathWoks link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/saveas.html).

In you LaTeX file use (if you saved your Simulink model as an eps file):

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering       
    \includegraphics{myfile.eps}
\end{figure}
```

Also, [this site](http://truongnghiem.wordpress.com/2010/07/07/export-simulink-models-to-publication-quality-figures/) can be of interest.

Comment: This works only for figures. The actual model cannot be saved this way.

Comment: @CountZero: Yes. I write in the answer (if your saved your Simulink model as an eps file). Thanks.

Comment: @Papiro: Thanks, especially for the quick response.

Answer (score 2):

## Quick and easy solution to save Simulink figures as eps:

The above mentioned solutions didnt work or were not exactly what I wanted so here is my solution.

**Step 1:**
Have your Simulink project open and type in the MATLAB Workspace:
`print -dmeta -s dummy.emf` and change `dummy` to the name of your Simulink file.

What this does is to save your Simulink figure in the emf file format.

**Step 2:**
Convert the emf file to eps:

Use an online converter [like this](https://convertio.co/)

**(Step 3:)** Use `\includegraphics`as always to place your figure in your LaTeX document.

**Advantages over the other methods:**

- Automatically removes unnecessary white spaces
- No need for additional Mathworks code piece
- Easy to follow for beginners like me

Answer (score 0):

I always use this [Mathworks](http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/fileexchange/16179-save2pdf) code piece. It removes additional space and works with all figures, I encountered.

Comment: Unfortunately, it works with figures not simulink models

Answer (score 0):

### Snapshot of a `Simulink` model:

- Open the `Simulink` system which you would like to print to file.
- Switch to the `Matlab` application and run the following code:

  - `print -dpdf       -s <outputFileName>.pdf %vector format`
  - `print -dpng -r225 -s <outputFileName>.png %raster format`

For `vector` format: I'm using r2013b, which has `pdf` capability despite the documentation completely omitting it.  Your usage may vary.

For `raster` format: The default resolution, `-r90` can be terrible.  Look for washed out connection lines.  I found this to occur straight through `-r200` when creating `.png` files.

### Snapshot of a `Stateflow` model:

- Open the `Stateflow` system which you would like to print to file.
- Switch to the `Matlab` application and run the following code:

  - `sfprint(gcs, 'png', '<outputFileName>.png')`

For `vector` format: `sfprint` does not yet have `.pdf` output capability.  You'll need to use `.eps` or `.svg` and a converter.  Packages exist within the `latex` environment to make the conversion.  Even so, you may not want `latex` to convert each time you compile. [See **Feature Requests**, below.]

For `raster` format: `sfprint` does not yet have an option to specify resolution.  Even so, I believe this command still provides improved resolution over the `File --> Print` method.

### `.PDF` Autocrop

To crop your `.pdf` down to its minimum margins, use the following code on the output `.pdf` from print:

- `!pdfcrop <outputFileName>.pdf <outputFileName>.pdf`

### Feature requests

In order to improve the process of exporting images from `Mathworks` products to a `latex` environment, I have recently requested that the `Simulink` and `Stateflow` teams consider the incorporation of additional functionality to the [`print`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/print.html) and [`sfprint`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stateflow/ref/sfprint.html) functions in future releases.

From what I understand, these functions have seen improvements over the past few years already, and I would thus consider them still open to additional development.

I requested the following features:

`print`:

- option to automatically crop margins/whitespace.
- option to specify margins/whitespace of crop option.

`sfprint`:

- option to print to `.pdf`. [option already exists in `print`].
- option to specify raster image resolution. [option already exists in `print`].
- option to automatically crop margins/whitespace.
- option to specify margins/whitespace of crop option.

### Contact `Mathworks` with additional insight.

My scope only considered `pdflatex`. Additional input from the community would likely be useful. Many of you may have needs which are not clear to me which would be better represented yourself. Your submissions would also demonstrate that support for the development of these features would be worthwhile.

```
To: US MathWorks Support <support@mathworks.com>
Re: Specifying image resolution with sfprint [ ref:_00Di0Ha1u._500i0THMmD:ref ]
```