# Extracting LaTeX source from HTML version of Feynman Lectures?

Tags: conversion, html

CalTech has placed Volume I of the classic *Feynman Lectures on Physics* online in HTML format, using MathJax to render the LaTeX formulas and SVG for the graphic images. It's pretty cool, and it looks like they did a pretty decent job with the conversion from the original book format:

- [The Feynman Lectures on Physics, Volume I](http://www.feynmanlectures.info/docroot/I_toc_sc.html)

Anyway, I would actually prefer to read these lectures in PDF format, as typeset by TeX and using TeX fonts and TeX's fine typesetting. What would be involved in programmatically extracting all the source formulas, text, and images from the web pages and converting these to LaTeX source files?

There is a nice list of tools in one of the answers to this question:

- [How do I convert HTML to LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3079/how-do-i-convert-html-to-latex)

but before diving in to explore those, I'm wondering if anyone can recommend a solution just by eyeballing the Feynman conversion HTML source.

Comment: It's probably fairly easy (if allowed) as its fairly simple html, just section heads and paragraphs and the math is all mathjax/latex anyway. But according to the site itself http://www.feynmanlectures.info/ it was converted to html from latex, but I guess that is the source of the publihed  book.

Comment: Ya, the LaTeX source for the individual formulas is pretty easy to find in the HTML source...which is really cool. By the way, this would be only for personal use, since I doubt CalTech would be pleased if anyone translated these into LaTeX and released the source into the wild for that.