# Import an HTML table into LaTeX

Tags: tables, html, import

How can I import an HTML table into LaTeX? I have many files  imported, so I can't convert each file to LaTeX.

Comment: And do you have the original tables too? Why do you not show us a table?

Comment: Why can't you convert each file to (La)TeX? You can use a batch script to convert them all... by the way, [here's a `sed` script to convert HTML to LaTeX](http://www.w3.org/Tools/html2latex.sed) ([source](http://www.w3.org/Tools/html2things.html)).

Comment: Related: [How do I convert HTML to LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3079/5764)