# Compiling Tex from website userinterface

Tags: pdftex, compiling

I am building a wordpress website which has a user interface where one can input information on project experiences. This information is saved on the server of the website.

I would like to save the collected information to a .tex file and compile it with PdfLatex. So basically, I am in need for leads on how to compile Latex from a website server. I can further develop these leads and research them thoroughly.

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3079/how-do-i-convert-html-to-latex (even Wordpress does only output HTML).

Comment: An example with php is presented on  https://mike42.me/blog/how-to-generate-professional-quality-pdf-files-from-php .