# Maintained tool to faithfully convert LaTeX/PDF to HTML?

Tags: html

There is a tool called [pdf2htmlex](http://coolwanglu.github.io/pdf2htmlEX/) that does an impressive job of converting PDF to HTML. Very faithful. Either [books](https://www.deeplearningbook.org) full of mathematics and diagrams have been faithfully converted.

Unfortunately, it is no longer maintained. Is anyone aware of another tool that is maintained that does as good a job of converting either PDF or LaTeX into HTML?

Comment: This question is the reversed of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3079/34551

Comment: _called pdf2htmlex that does an impressive job of converting PDF to HTML_ I've been trying it. It does good job, except the quality of rendering is horrible. The font is too light and the math is hard to read. I tried zooming to be able to read. But the underlining font is too light. I could not figure how to improve it. Also the tool is abandoned. Too bad, as it looks promising. But I do not want to waste time on software that no one maintains.

Comment: I looked at your book. You can see that in your own book. Hard to read as the font is just too light and math hard to read. No one will read this. Compare this to mathjax. Much much better quality rendering.  tex4ht is much better. But if pdf2htmlEX can improve the quality of the fonts and rendering, then it can have potential.

Answer (score 6):

I'd recommend [make4ht](https://github.com/michal-h21/make4ht) which, from the documentation:

> make4ht is a simple build system for tex4ht , TeX to XML converter. It provides
> a command line tool that drive the conversion process. It also provides a library
> which can be used to create customized conversion tools

The author of `make4ht` is [michal-h21](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2891/michal-h21) and is a very active contributor to this site.

Let's use the following small example, `mwe.tex`, in what follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Here is some text. And here is some mathematical content $y=x^2$.
\end{document}
```

### example 1

Running

```
 make4ht.exe mwe.tex
```

gives the output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US" > 
<head><title></title> 
<meta  charset="iso-8859-1" /> 
<meta name="generator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)" /> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mwe.css" /> 
<meta name="src" content="mwe.tex" /> 
</head><body 
>
<!--l. 5--><p class="noindent" >Here is some text. And here is some mathematical content <span 
class="cmmi-10">y </span>= <span 
class="cmmi-10">x</span><sup><span 
class="cmr-7">2</span></sup>. </p> 
</body> 
</html>
```

### example 2

From here we can customise the output by employing *configuration* files; if you have the following:

### `roxy.cfg`

```
\Preamble{mathml,-css,NoFonts}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">\Hnewline</script>\Hnewline}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

and run

```
make4ht.exe -f html5 -c roxy.cfg mwe.tex
```

then you receive

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US" > 
<head> <title></title> 
<meta  charset="iso-8859-1" /> 
<meta name="generator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)" /> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="\aa:CssFile " /> 
<meta name="src" content="mwe.tex"> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"> 
</script> 
</head><body 
>
<!--l. 5--><p class="noindent" >Here is some text. And here is some mathematical content
<!--l. 5--><math 
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"  
display="inline" ><mi 
>y</mi> <mo 
class="MathClass-rel">=</mo> <msup><mrow 
><mi 
>x</mi></mrow><mrow 
><mn>2</mn></mrow></msup 
></math>.
 
</body> 
</html>
```

### example 3

If you have [html tidy](http://www.html-tidy.org/) installed, then you can customise your build process to employ it by using the following `roxy.mk4` file:

## `roxy.mk4`

```
Make:match("html$", "tidy -m -config html-tidy.txt -i ${filename}")
```

and an `html-tidy.txt` configuration file

```
// sample config file for HTML tidy
indent: auto
indent-spaces: 2
quiet: yes
output-xhtml: no
output-html: yes
```

then you can run

```
make4ht.exe -f html5 -e roxy.mk4 -c roxy.cfg mwe.tex
```

to receive

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta name="generator" content=
  "HTML Tidy for HTML5 for Windows version 5.6.0">
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="generator" content=
  "TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)">
  <meta name="viewport" content=
  "width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="\aa:CssFile">
  <meta name="src" content="mwe.tex">
  <script src=
  "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!--l. 5-->
  <p class="noindent">Here is some text. And here is some
  mathematical content <!--l. 5--><math xmlns=
  "http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="inline">
  <mi>
    y
  </mi>
  <mo class="MathClass-rel">
    =
  </mo>
  <msup>
    <mrow>
      <mi>
        x
      </mi>
    </mrow>
    <mrow>
      <mn>
        2
      </mn>
    </mrow>
  </msup></math>.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice answer, would it be possible to add links to HTML documents generated with this tool, so that one can get a concrete idea of what kinds of results can be obtained? Thanks.

Comment: Good suggestion...

Comment: that converts from TEX to html

Answer (score 0):

Try [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/getting-started.html)

long version:

```
pandoc -f filename.pdf -t html -o output.html
```

short version:

```
pandoc filename.pdf -o output.html
```

There is an extensive list of examples for *any* kind of conversion [here](https://pandoc.org/demos.html), and it's super fast!

On MacOS, all you have to do to install is:

```
brew install pandoc
```

Comment: Does not work, I get:
"Unknown reader: pdf
Pandoc can convert to PDF, but not from PDF."
`